# How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, function, concatenation

Right now, I have a SQL Query like this one:

```
SELECT X, Y FROM POINTS
```

It returns results like so:

```
X    Y
----------
12   3
15   2
18   12
20   29
```

I'd like to return results all in one row, like this (suitable for using in an HTML <AREA> tag):

```
XYLIST
----------
12,3,15,2,18,12,20,29
```

Is there a way to do this using just SQL?

Comment: If you want your application to scale, it would be better to do this kind of thing outside the database. The database will almost always be your bottleneck.

Comment: I wonder why the good answer went away?

Comment: @Joseph Bui - Believe me, I know. Unfortunately the project lead insists I do it this way.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XYList varchar(MAX)
SET @XYList = ''

SELECT @XYList = @XYList + CONVERT(varchar, X) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar, Y) + ','
FROM POINTS

-- Remove last comma
SELECT LEFT(@XYList, LEN(@XYList) - 1)
```

Comment: Is it me or doesn't this work on a linked server? When i try something like `SELECT @List = @List + CONVERT(varchar, ID) + ','
FROM LinkedServer.MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable` it always returns only one ID. A `Select *` returns many ID's.

Answer (score 101):

Thanks for the quick and helpful answers guys!

I just found another fast way to do this too:

```
SELECT  STUFF(( SELECT ',' + X + ',' + Y
                FROM Points
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 1, '') AS XYList
```

Credit goes to this guy:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200217202303/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/mnf/archive/2007/10/02/t-sql-user-defined-function-to-concatenate-column-to-csv-string.aspx)

Comment: I really like this solution the most. Easy to use and only one line to add in any SQL.

Comment: Note:  This method causes special characters to be replaced by their XML equivalent.  IOW, Barnes & Noble becomes Barnes &amp; Noble

Answer (score 18):

Starting in SQL 2017, you can use `STRING_AGG`

```
SELECT STRING_AGG (X + ',' + Y, ',') AS XYLIST
FROM POINTS
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 15):

Using the `COALESCE` trick, you don't have to worry about the trailing comma:

```
DECLARE @XYList AS varchar(MAX) -- Leave as NULL

SELECT @XYList = COALESCE(@XYList + ',', '') + CONVERT(varchar, X) + ',' + CONVERT(varchar, Y)
FROM POINTS
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @s VarChar(8000)
SET @s = ''

SELECT @s = @s + ',' + CAST(X AS VarChar) + ',' + CAST(Y AS VarChar) 
FROM POINTS

SELECT @s
```

Just get rid of the leading comma