# String aggregation in SSRS 2005

Tags: .net, reporting-services, reporting, reportingservices-2005

Using BIDS 2005 to create rdl reports.  I want to have the report aggregate all the strings in a data group.  I was looking for something along the lines of Concatenate(Fields!CompanyName.Value, ","), or Join, or equivalent.  But it would have to iterate over all the records in the scope given.

I am creating a report of a user's activities in a calendar format (looking like the google's month view calendar)  But if a user has multiple activities on a single day I want all of them to show up in the same 'day box'.  Is this a problem needing aggregation or is there some other way to get a SSRS report to do this, I have tried to figure a way to get the matrix to do it for me but I am hitting walls.

Comment: Thank you Joel for the tag corrections, I will be sure to use those next time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The usual way to do aggregate concatenation in SSRS is with custom code. See here for an example:

http://blogs.msdn.com/suryaj/archive/2007/08/11/string-aggregation.aspx

Here's the custom code in basic form:

```
Private CurrGroupBy As String = String.Empty
Private ConcatVal As String = String.Empty
Public Function AggConcat(GroupBy as String, ElementVal as String) as String
    If CurrGroupBy = GroupBy Then
        ConcatVal = ConcatVal & ", " & ElementVal 
    Else
        CurrGroupBy = GroupBy 
        ConcatVal = ElementVal 
    End If
    Return ConcatVal 
End Function
```

Followed by this expression at the grouping level you want to display:

```
=RunningValue(
     Code.AggConcat(
         Fields!YourFieldToGroupBy.Value
       , Fields!YourFieldToConcat.Value
       )
   , Last
   , "YourGroupName" 
   )
```

"YourGroupName" is typically "table1_Group1", if it is the first table and the first group you have created in the report, and if you didn't specify a different name.

Comment: That has worked so far thank you!  This is an approach I had read of, but I had also read that using the shared variables (CurrGroupBy and ConcatVal) was a bad idea, saying that they are shared among all instances of the report.  Bad thing to do on a web server. Do you know if this is true?

Comment: That may be true, I don't know. If you find out please post something here, and I'll wikify the answer.

Comment: This is a great help. None of the examples in the docs seem to show calling a custom function for RunningValue.

Comment: Thank you! Do you got any ideea how to join only the distinct ones?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way to concatenate values together by a grouped value.  Use something like this as the expression:

```
=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!GroupField.Value, Fields!GroupField.Value, Fields!ConcatField.Value, "DataSet1"), ",")
```