# RDLC - Hide a table row

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have an RDLC report with a table in it. I want to hide a string column if there is no data present in any of the rows(supress if blank sort of thing). I have been googling for the last 2 hrs and trying with different suggestions but i can not make it work. 
I tried the following so far.

Set the expression for the Hidden attribute of the column to
=IIf(Fields!Category.Value = "", True, False)
But it is checking only the first row but not the entire row set.

Trying to create a concatenated string with the field values, so if the final string is empty i'll hide the table column. But i can't find a way of concatenating a string column from a table. Runningtotal() works with only numbers it seems.

Can some one point me to the right direction.

initially i thought it is very easy, but doesn't seem so.

Comment: I would try to use Hidden=IIf(IsNothing(MAX(Fields!Category.Value)),true,false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use CountDistinct?

I think something like this should do the trick

```
=(CountDistinct(Fields!Category.Value) > 1) Or (Fields!Category.Value != "")
```

Or you can try to make a custom string aggregate function
[String aggregation in SSRS 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972616/string-aggregation-in-ssrs-2005)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help, it worked. What i did was CountDistinct(Fields!Category.Value) = 0 Then Hide the table column.