# How to show a dataset field in a single textbox ssrs

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, dataset, reporting

I have created a dataset in SSRS which is hooked to a Stored procedure.  The stored procedure resultset includes the following columns
OutputID, Timestamp, ProductName, Price, ProductNumber.

I show the above in a tablix in my report which works perfectly fine.  I have about 10 rows.

The question I have is

I want a textbox on my report which will show productNumber as follows
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

I am fairly new to SSRS so forgive my ignorance.

The backend is SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: This would probably be a lot easier on the SQL side as a new column - check out [this link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919259/multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-combine-column-sql) for a possible solution.

Comment: Hi All, I have found a partial solution and it works. However I am unable to get distinct values. Any help is greatly appreciated. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/ceabc828-d389-45bd-9ad0-580cc857686c/ssrs-2008-r2-concatenate-all-fields-values-in-one-string

Comment: Google says to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046186/concatenate-distinct-row-values-for-field-in-reporting-services) ... SQL still seems easier to me but maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the textbox expression
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, "FIELD NAME,"DATASETNAME"),",")

this will concatenate the result with comma