# How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, pivot, string-aggregation

I have a simple query:

```
select * from countries
```

with the following results:

```
country_name
------------
Albania
Andorra
Antigua
.....
```

I would like to return the results in one row, so like this:

```
Albania, Andorra, Antigua, ...
```

Of course, I can write a PL/SQL function to do the job (I already did in Oracle 10g), but is there a nicer, preferably non-Oracle-specific solution (or may be a built-in function) for this task?

I would generally use it to avoid multiple rows in a sub-query, so if a person has more then one citizenship, I do not want her/him to be a duplicate in the list.

My question is based on the similar question on [SQL server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180032/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-sql-server-2005).

**UPDATE**:
My function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION APPEND_FIELD (sqlstr in varchar2, sep in varchar2 ) return varchar2 is
ret varchar2(4000) := '';
TYPE cur_typ IS REF CURSOR;
rec cur_typ;
field varchar2(4000);
begin
     OPEN rec FOR sqlstr;
     LOOP
         FETCH rec INTO field;
         EXIT WHEN rec%NOTFOUND;
         ret := ret || field || sep;
     END LOOP;
     if length(ret) = 0 then
          RETURN '';
     else
          RETURN substr(ret,1,length(ret)-length(sep));
     end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Here is a simple way without stragg or creating a function.

```
create table countries ( country_name varchar2 (100));

insert into countries values ('Albania');

insert into countries values ('Andorra');

insert into countries values ('Antigua');


SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (country_name , ','), 2) csv
      FROM (SELECT country_name , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY country_name ) rn,
                   COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
              FROM countries)
     WHERE rn = cnt
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1;

CSV                                                                             
--------------------------
Albania,Andorra,Antigua                                                         

1 row selected.
```

As others have mentioned, if you are on 11g R2 or greater, you can now use listagg which is much simpler.

```
select listagg(country_name,', ') within group(order by country_name) csv
  from countries;

CSV                                                                             
--------------------------
Albania, Andorra, Antigua

1 row selected.
```

Comment: Nice short solution but a couple typos marred it.

This line should read:

FROM (SELECT country_name , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY country_name ) rn,

Comment: JoshL's suggestion of using the LISTAGG function is highly preferable for anyone using 11.2 or newer.

Comment: Just make sure your concatenated results don't exceed the VARCHAR2 max length limit of your oracle database (most likely 4000 bytes) otherwise you will run into `ORA-01489 result of string concatenation is too long`.

Comment: @JanM **[Comment 1 of 2]** So, this is where I run into some challenges. I use [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672269/how-to-remove-duplicates-from-comma-separated-list-by-regex-in-oracle-regexp-rep) to remove the duplicates, but this does not work if I reach the VARCHAR2 max limit first.

Comment: @JanM **[Comment 2 of 2]** Next, I try to convert it to a [clob using RTRIM,XMLAGG,XMLELEMENT, and GETCLOBVAL()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395678/result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long-after-using-to-clob), which I then cast back to [VARCHAR2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282195/ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-clob-00932-00000). However, the run time for the query turns into hours rather than 15 minutes. Do you have any recommendations of other approaches? Also, I saw a suggestion for creating a custom function instead.

Comment: how this query work if I join two table and want to get a column by comma separated value from 2nd table?

Answer (score 135):

The `WM_CONCAT` function (if included in your database, pre Oracle 11.2) or `LISTAGG` (starting Oracle 11.2) should do the trick nicely. For example, this gets a comma-delimited list of the table names in your schema:

```
select listagg(table_name, ', ') within group (order by table_name) 
  from user_tables;
```

or

```
select wm_concat(table_name) 
  from user_tables;
```

[More details/options](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php)

[Link to documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions089.htm)

Comment: This command is faster than @Decci.7 has provided +1 and I like simple one-liners :D

Comment: Note that Oracle don't recommend using `WM_CONCAT` as it is undocumented and unsupported: [WMSYS.WM_CONCAT Should Not Be Used For Customer Applications, It Is An Internal Function (Doc ID 1336219.1)](https://support.oracle.com/CSP/main/article?cmd=show&type=NOT&doctype=HOWTO&id=1336219.1)

Comment: WM_CONCAT was dropped in 12c.  Anyone using this undocumented function is in for a surprise when they upgrade.

Comment: listagg is perfect,but the wm_concat not works with Oracle12

Answer (score 21):

For Oracle you can use [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

Comment: In Oracle 11.2 as JoshL pointed out.

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Fixed link. Thanks

Answer (score 20):

You can use this as well:

```
SELECT RTRIM (
          XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (e, country_name || ',')).EXTRACT ('//text()'),
          ',')
          country_name
  FROM countries;
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in Oracle 10g.

Answer (score 20):

you can try this query.

```
select listagg(country_name,',') within group (order by country_name) cnt 
from countries;
```

Comment: Listagg has been introduced in Oracle 11g Release 2.

Comment: this wouldn't work if there are too many columns.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way it is to use the Oracle collect function.

You can also do this:

```
  SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT deptno,
               CASE
                 WHEN Row_number()
                        over (
                          PARTITION BY deptno
                          ORDER BY ename) = 1 THEN Stragg(ename)
                 over (
                   PARTITION BY deptno
                   ORDER BY ename ROWS BETWEEN unbounded
                 preceding AND unbounded following)
               END enames
        FROM   emp)
WHERE  enames IS NOT NULL
```

Visit the site ask tom and search on 'stragg'  or 'string concatenation' . Lots of
examples. There is also a not-documented oracle function to achieve your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I needed a similar thing and found the following solution.

```
select RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e,country_name || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()'),',') country_name from
```

Comment: While it works, I dont recommend this solution to anybody. I saw an update command on table with only 80 000 rows using this solution and it was run for 6-8 hours.

Comment: @csadam What do you recommend for larger rows, where the end goal is to remove duplicates to avoid the varchar2 4000 bytes limitation?

Comment: @myidealab You can find some workarounds [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/managing-overflows-in-listagg) and [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques). To remove duplicates you can try an inner select with DISTINCT. Maybe the best solution is to create a custom function for these cases... However you could also redesign your solution, does it really have to use a 4000 char long string?

Answer (score 2):

In this example we are creating a function to bring a comma delineated list of distinct line level AP invoice hold reasons into one field for header level query:

```
 FUNCTION getHoldReasonsByInvoiceId (p_InvoiceId IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2

  IS

  v_HoldReasons   VARCHAR2 (1000);

  v_Count         NUMBER := 0;

  CURSOR v_HoldsCusror (p2_InvoiceId IN NUMBER)
   IS
     SELECT DISTINCT hold_reason
       FROM ap.AP_HOLDS_ALL APH
      WHERE status_flag NOT IN ('R') AND invoice_id = p2_InvoiceId;
BEGIN

  v_HoldReasons := ' ';

  FOR rHR IN v_HoldsCusror (p_InvoiceId)
  LOOP
     v_Count := v_COunt + 1;

     IF (v_Count = 1)
     THEN
        v_HoldReasons := rHR.hold_reason;
     ELSE
        v_HoldReasons := v_HoldReasons || ', ' || rHR.hold_reason;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN v_HoldReasons;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have always had to write some PL/SQL for this or I just concatenate a ',' to the field and copy into an editor and remove the CR from the list giving me the single line.

That is,

```
select country_name||', ' country from countries
```

A little bit long winded both ways.

If you look at Ask Tom you will see loads of possible solutions but they all revert to type declarations and/or PL/SQL

[Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE
((SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT country_name + ', ' AS CountryName
FROM         country_name
ORDER BY country_name FOR XML PATH('')), 
'&<CountryName>', ''), '&<CountryName>', '') AS CountryNames
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use this query to do the above task

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(max)
SELECT @test = COALESCE(@test + ',', '') + field2 FROM #test SELECT field2= @test
```

for detail and step by step explanation visit the following link
http://oops-solution.blogspot.com/2011/11/sql-server-convert-table-column-data.html