# i want Oracle Query for Formatted Output

Tags: oracle

Following is my table deign

```
Ecode           Degree              YOQ
7654321         SSC                 2000
7654321         HSC                 2002
7654321         Bcom                2006
7654321         MCA                 2010
7654322         SSC                 2002
7654322         HSC                 2004
7654322         Bcom                2007
7654323         SSC                 2002
7654323         HSC                 2004
7654323         BE                  2008
```

i want following formatted output using oracle query

```
Ecode        Degree                           year
7654321      SSC,HSC,Bcom,MCA                 2000,2002,2006,2010          
7654322      SSC,HSC,Bcom                     2002,2004,2007
7654323      SSC,HSC,BE                       2002,2004,2008
```

Thanks in Advance

[Vivek shah](http://reply2viveksshah.blogspot.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ecode,wm_concat(DEGREE),wm_concat(yoQ) FROM TABLE_NAME  GROUP BY ecode