# plsql query return result into single row as concat

Tags: string, plsql, aggregate

```
select col1 from tablename
```

returns 2 rows, I want to concat these two data rows into a single column separated by a comma.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a cursor to loop through the returned rows one by one and concatenate as you like.

Comment: NO i need to do it only using a query

Comment: @Faisal Khan - Daniel Emge's solution here should be helpful for you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples of same kind of situation:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_converting_rows_columns.htm

Comment: I checked that the first one is at least working with no problems.