# Is there a MySQL equivalent to PostgreSQL array_to_string

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I'm trying to find the MySQL equivalent of the PostgreSQL functions **array** and **array_to_string** and came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326868/equivalent-to-postgresql-array-array-to-string-functions-in-oracle-9i) but asking for oracle9i which doesn't help me. I need to achieve this with MySQL but even Google can't seem to find any suitable answers.

So you don't have to read two posts, here is a repeat of the question:

> In PostgreSQL, using the array and array_to_string functions can do the following:
>
> Given the table "people":
>
> ```
> id | name
> ---------
> 1  | bob
> 2  | alice
> 3  | jon
> ```
>
> The SQL:
>
> ```
> SELECT array_to_string(array(SELECT name FROM people), ',') AS names;
> ```
>
> Will return:
>
> ```
> names
> -------------
> bob,alice,jon
> ```

Anyone have any ideas how to achieve this in MySQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) .
e.g:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS names FROM people GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: @DangerPaws, See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for more details.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that! Exactly what I needed :)
@Johan Thanks for the link

Comment: I take it from the documentation that I can't put a SELECT statement inside the GROUP_CONCAT function?

Comment: @myself, correction you can put a SELECT statement inside the GROUP_CONCAT but need to wrap the SELECT statement in an extra pair of brackets like this: GROUP_CONCAT((SELECT...))