# Mysql Insert Multiple Rows with comma separated values with sql statement alone

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

The intention to execute multiple sql insert statements without running them into some kind of loop in node.js etc.

A typical sql statement looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO session_speaker(session_id, speaker_id) VALUES(?, ?);
INSERT INTO session_speaker(session_id, speaker_id) VALUES(?, ?);
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO session_speaker(session_id, speaker_id) VALUES(?, ?), (?, ?);
```

The ordinary node.js loop looks like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < request.body.length; i++) {
    queryRequest.sql += "INSERT INTO session_speaker(session_id, speaker_id) VALUES(?, ?);";
    queryRequest.values.push(request.body[i].id, request.params.id);
}
```

Intention/Question:

Exploring a way if possible to pass `request.body` to an intelligent SQL that takes array itself or maybe comma separated list of values and insert multiple rows from there without node.js loop.

`request.body` looks like this (changeable to meet the requirements)

```
[
  {
    "id": 12
  },
  {
    "id": 34
  }
]
```

Comment: You realize of course that all you would be doing is transferring the loop to the database, if you actually figured out a way to do it.

Comment: yup something like that without going into stored procedures, any sql function that works with arrays or comma separated values to do multiple insert, that's what the quest is about...

Comment: is this promising? http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic760680-338-1.aspx

Comment: Did you mean something like `insert into table values(jsonObject)`?

Comment: not storing json object directly but basically sql to insert multiple records based on a pattern, basically sql is handling the array or comma separated values as @DanBracuk suggested.

Comment: Then you need to convert comma separated values into rows first and then do insert statement.

Comment: Can sql handle arrays or comma separated values natively with insert statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this brings me closer to what I'm looking for.

https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/814

As per dougwilson comment there and his solution for nested arrays, I can simply pass the multi object array to the query and it will insert multiple records at once.

```
var currentLogs = [
  [ 'Server', 'Socketio online', 'Port 3333', '2014-05-14 14:41:11' ],
  [ 'Server', 'Waiting for Pi to connect...', 'Port: 8082', '2014-05-14 14:41:11' ]
];

pool.query('INSERT INTO logs_debug (socket_id,message,data,logged) VALUES ?', [currentLogs])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible. 
Take a look at this reference.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html

Here is what you can do.

1. Select your object data
2. Convert to array
3. Unnest the array ( make array in column view ) reference: [UNNEST function in MYSQL like POSTGRESQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27364788/unnest-function-in-mysql-like-postgresql), This function needs a string so convert your data (array ) into data (string) here is reference: [Is there a MySQL equivalent to PostgreSQL array_to_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162324/is-there-a-mysql-equivalent-to-postgresql-array-to-string)
4. Use `insert into select`  reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

At the end, your code something like this:

```
insert  into session_speaker(session_id, speaker_id)  
select unnest_mysql ( arrayToString (dataTOArray( stringtojson (json_string) ) ) )
```

`json_string` = this is your data from php

`dataTOArray`  = this function convert your data to mysql json to array

`dataTOArray`  = this is to convert array to string  ex. `[1,2,3]` to `'1,2,3'`
`unnest_mysql`  = your string to row data

```
 string '1,2,3'
 --view like 

 |-------String-----|
 |---------1--------|
 |---------2--------|
 |---------3--------|
 |----------- ------|
 So when you insert this , it will become row in your table
```

Note: Change my function to MySQL specific function.

Comment: I've researched a lot but is there a way you can please also provide an sql statement that works in the above case for the mysql database? I'm using node.js and request.body contains the parsed json object.