# sql to display all names in 1 row (1 string)

Tags: select, postgresql-8.4

`ad_org` table with column `id` & `name`

**ad_org**

```
            ad_org_id             |   name    
----------------------------------+-----------

 357947E87C284935AD1D783CF6F099A1 | Spain

 43D590B4814049C6B85C6545E8264E37 | Main

 5EFF95EB540740A3B10510D9814EFAD5 | USA

 2878085215E54C73A04D394BFD170733 | India

 22669845D93A49A98932CE29AE02E0FD | Honkong
```

how to get output of all names(in 1 string) in this way from the above database

`Spain | Main | USA | India | Honkong`

in 1 select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `string_agg`.

```
SELECT string_agg("name", ' | ') FROM thetable;
```

For older PostgreSQL, you must use `array_agg` and `array_to_string`:

```
SELECT array_to_string( array_agg("name"), ' | ') FROM thetable;
```

If you want a particular order, put it in the aggregate, e.g for alphabetical:

```
SELECT string_agg("name", ' | ' ORDER BY "name") FROM thetable;
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) 
                    from yourtable
                    group by ColumnName, id
                    order by id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select value, ColumnName
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for ColumnName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

[Click here for Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2312/3)

Comment: im using postgresql 8.4, and output should be

`Spain | Main | USA | India | Honkong` names of all org in 1 string

Answer (score 0):

got it by searching..

[Equivalent to PostgreSQL array() / array_to_string() functions in Oracle 9i](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4326868/2750968)

`select array_to_string(array(select name from ad_org), '|') as names;`