# I want to select a column "B" as a list when it's column "A" is the same

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

I want to select column "B" as a list when it's column "A" is the same. Say I have:

```
A                | B 
-----------------------------------
10000            | 5000         
10000            | 5000         
10001            | 9090        
10002            | 9090         
10000            | 9090
```

As a result, I would like to have:

```
A                | B 
-----------------------------------
10000            | '5000,5000,9090'               
10001            | '9090'        
10002            | '9090'
```

How should I go about this? Thanks all!

Comment: 8.4 is no longer maintained. You should _really_ upgrade to a supported version

Comment: Hi, @a_horse_with_no_name. Unfortunately, it's not up to me to decide. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
select A, array_to_string( array_agg("B"), ' , ') from tablename GROUP BY A order by A
```

for more reference visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22826567/2750968)