# I have a query that was written in Postgresql. What is the Oracle equivalent of this query?

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I have a query written in Postgresql as I have given below. Can you write the Oracle equivalent of this query?

My query;

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT view_cus_result.channel
       FROM view_cus_result
      GROUP BY view_cus_result.channel))
```

How would this query be written in Oracle?

Comment: In Postgres, the `array_to_string` function requires a [second argument](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-array.html)

Comment: You should not tag `MySQL`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326868/equivalent-to-postgresql-array-array-to-string-functions-in-oracle-9i

Comment: Removed mysql tag, since that brand of SQL database does not appear to be considered in this question.

Comment: maybe listagg function?

Answer (score 1):

The given SQL lacks a second argument for `array_to_string`. So I'll assume you have this:

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY( SELECT view_cus_result.channel
       FROM view_cus_result
      GROUP BY view_cus_result.channel), ',');
```

In Oracle you can use `listagg`:

```
SELECT listagg(channel, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY channel)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT channel FROM view_cus_result);
```

In version 19c and later, you can use the `distinct` keyword:

```
SELECT listagg(DISTINCT channel, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY channel)
FROM view_cus_result;
```

Answer (score 1):

The subquery gets you a distinct list of channels. You make this an array and turn that array into a string. I am surprised, though, that works for you, because `ARRAY_TO_STRING` is lacking the delimiter parameter which is not optional.

A simpler way of writing this in PostgreSQL (with a comma as delimiter) is:

```
select string_agg(distinct channel, ',')
from view_cus_result;
```

In Oracle it is `LISTAGG` instead of `STRING_AGG` and the order is not optional:

```
select listagg(distinct channel, ',') within group (order by channel)
from view_cus_result;
```