# SQL query construction issue

Tags: sql

There two tables:

**Table1**

```
field1 | field2
```

**Table2**

```
field1
“string1”
“string2”
```

I need to insert concatenation of table2.field1 values into table1, so it looks like

```
insert into table1(field1, field2) values (1, “string1string2”);
```

How can I do it? Is there any SQL-standard way to do it?

PS: string1 and string2 are values of the field1 column.

PPS: the main subtask of my question is, how can I get the result of select query into one row? All examples I've seen just use concatenation, but in all your examples SELECT subquery does not return string concatenation for all values of the table2.field1 column.

Comment: Alexandr - did you just vote down 5 answers? Nuts. Did you even read my answer properly before stating "but in all your examples"?

Comment: Richard aka cyberkiwi, unfortunately I cannot check it. And I cannot remove my vote down for your answer, sorry:(((

Comment: @Alexandr - It really shows bad attitude to downvote people who are trying to help you when your question was not even clear in first place...

Comment: Richard aka cyberkiwi, could you pleas edit your answer so i could vote up?

Comment: @Alex Richard can't see your comment, use @Richard to send him notification. (or make a comment on his own answer)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, thank you for the tip. Richard has already updated his answer and I voted it up.

Comment: @Alex cheers! What about the other answers? I agree with Sachin that it's not a good idea to globally downvote answers just because they were not accurate enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ANSI standard SQL way to do this.

But in MySQL you can use GROUP_CONCAT

```
insert into table1 ( field1, field2 )
select 1, group_concat(field1) from table2
```

In SQL Server 2005 and later you can use XML PATH,

```
insert into table1 ( field1, field2 )
select 1, (select field1 from table2
           for xml path(''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

In Oracle, you can refer to Stack Overflow question [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990).

Comment: Looks like somebody has been on a markdown spree... +1 to offset that because you've explicitly stating that there is no Ansi-standard SQL way to do this, and given a couple of examples

Comment: thanks for your replay and especially for the last link for Oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (FIELD1, FILED2) VALUES (1, CONCAT("string1", "string2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
insert into table1(field1, field2)
select table2.field1, table2.string1 || table2.string2 from table2;
```

You can add a where clause to the query to select only some entries from table2 :

```
insert into table1(field1, field2)
select table2.field1, table2.string1 || table2.string2 from table2
where table2.field = 'whatever';
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I'd try with</s>

```
insert table1 select field1, string1+string2 from table2
```

tested with MSSQL Server 2008

```
create table #t1 (n int, s varchar(200))
create table #t2 (n int, s1 varchar(100), s2 varchar(100))

insert #t2 values (1, 'one', 'two')    -- worked without into ???
insert #t2 values (2, 'three', 'four') -- worked without into ???
insert #t1 select n, s1+s2 from #t2    -- worked without into ???

select * from #t1

drop table #t1
drop table #t2
```

After the edit:

No, if you have no way to identify the lines in table2 **and sort them the way you want** it is impossible. Remember that, in the absence of a `order by` in the SQL statement, lines can be returned in any order whatsoever

Comment: @downvoter: would you please state your reason fot the downvote. Hopefully I will learn and create better answers in the future. (I've tested that code in my database; and it works for me)

Comment: re: downvote, see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83548/revealing-voting-patterns-new-trend

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this is SQL server,

```
Insert into table1 (field1, field2)
select field1, string1 + string2 
from table2
```

In oracle you will do it as -

```
Insert into table1 (field1, field2)
select field1, string1 || string2 
from table2
```

Comment: Looks like somebody has been on a markdown spree... +1 to offset that because you've indicated that this is different for different databases, and given a couple of examples

Comment: It wasn't me, I got hit too though I cannot imagine why. This answer isn't right anyway, since it misread the question - string1 and string2 are **values**

Comment: @richard - I know that your answer using group_concat(), etc is more accurately answering the precise question... I just got annoyed because the OP simply downvoted every answer he'd been given without comment (even your right answer)

Comment: @Richard - I understood what you are saying. yes, you are right. However, can you explain why you are using that `.value('.'` in your answer?

Comment: the `.value('.'` is used to handle text than can turn into XML-entities.