# Building a comma-separated list of values in an Oracle SQL statement

Tags: oracle, select-into

I'm trying to build a comma-separated list of values out of a field in Oracle.

I find some sample code that does this:

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(5000)
SELECT @List = COALESCE(@List + ', ' + Display, Display)
FROM TestTable
Order By Display
```

But when I try that I always get an error about the FROM keyword not being were it was expected. I can use `SELECT INTO` and it works but if I have more than one row I get the fetch error.

Why can't I do as follows:

```
SELECT myVar = Field1
FROM myTable
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Answer (score 7):

In Oracle, you would use one of the many [string aggregation techniques](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) collected by Tim Hall on this page.

If you are using 11.2,

```
SELECT LISTAGG(display, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY display) AS employees
  INTO l_list
  FROM TestTable
```

In earlier versions, my preference would be to use the user-defined aggregate function approach (Tim's is called `string_agg`) to do

```
SELECT string_agg( display )
  INTO l_list
  FROM TestTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try DBMS_UTILITY.COMMA_TO_TABLE and TABLE_TO_COMMA to split/join csv:

```
DECLARE
  l_list1   VARCHAR2(50) := 'Tom,Dick,Harry,William';
  l_list2   VARCHAR2(50);
  l_tablen  BINARY_INTEGER;
  l_tab     DBMS_UTILITY.uncl_array;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_list1 : ' || l_list1);

  DBMS_UTILITY.comma_to_table (
     list   => l_list1,
     tablen => l_tablen,
     tab    => l_tab);

  FOR i IN 1 .. l_tablen LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(i || ' : ' || l_tab(i));
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_UTILITY.table_to_comma (
     tab    => l_tab,
     tablen => l_tablen,
     list   => l_list2);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_list2 : ' || l_list2);
END;
```

Comment: This utility only works with tokens which conform to Oracle's naming conventions (30 characters in length, can't start with a number, etc).  Or at least it used to.  It may have changed in later versions of the database - I haven't used it in years.

Comment: @APC : showing my age I guess ;-)  I'm really not that old, but I feel old sometimes (esp reading some of the questions on SO ).

Comment: and sorry VBAHole, my comment about questions on SO wasn't directed at you!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot insert multiple values into a single variable, unless you concatenate them somehow.

To get only a single value (not sure of the oracle syntax),

```
select @myVar = select top 1 Field1 From myTable
```

Otherwise, to concatenate the values (again, not sure of Oracle)

```
set @myVar = ''  -- Get rid of NULL
select @myVar = @MyVar + ', ' +  Field1 From myTable
```