# Is there any function in oracle similar to group_concat in mysql?

Tags: sql, oracle

My inputs are in this way.

```
col1   col2
1      a
1      b
2      c
2      d
2      e
```

O/p: Should Be like

```
col1    col2
1       a,b
2       c,d,e
```

I want a query that can be fired at DB level. I've tried various ways, but wasn't able to make this out...

Comment: Do you want the query to work both in Oracle and in MySQL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120706/is-there-an-oracle-sql-query-that-aggregates-multiple-rows-into-one-row) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12145379/how-to-retrieve-two-columns-data-in-a-b-format-in-oracle) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822700/building-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-an-oracle-sql-statement) or ...

Comment: ...or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256810/how-to-select-multiple-rows-in-a-single-row-with-condition-oracle)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

**11g and higher:** Use [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030):

```
SELECT 
    col1,
    LISTAGG(col2, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col2) "names"
FROM table_x
GROUP BY col1
```

**10g and lower:** One method is to use a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_comma_separated_value (input_val  in  number)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  return_text  VARCHAR2(10000) := NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR x IN (SELECT col2 FROM table_name WHERE col1 = input_val) LOOP
    return_text := return_text || ',' || x.col2 ;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN LTRIM(return_text, ',');
END;
/
```

To use the function:

```
select col1, get_comma_separated_value(col1) from table_name
```

**Note:** There is an (unsupported) function `WM_CONCAT` available on certain older versions of Oracle, which might help you out - see [here for details](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques#wm_concat).

**In MySQL:**

```
SELECT col1, GROUP_CONCAT(col2) FROM table_name GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: LISTAGG will throw a "ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long" if result exceeds VARCHAR2 limits. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29008456/848072 for custom aggregate function