# Selecting multiple values of other column basing on distinct values of column on same table

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

I am having a table in oracle `my_table` like

```
userid            card_no
-------           -------
 111                 A1
 111                 A5
 112                 A3
 113                 A4
 111                 A6
 112                 A8
 113                 A9
```

In my JSP page I want to show:

```
------------------------
user_id   card numbers
-------   --------------
111       A1,A5,A6.
112       A3,A8
113       A4,A9
------------------------
```

`GROUP BY` IS NOT GIVING RESULTS .

Comment: what version of oracle are you using?

Comment: You have to use some column concatenation functions....

Comment: see the similar question in link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Oracle 10g onward you  can achieve the desired result by using `model` clause:

```
SQL> with t1(userid, card_no) as(
  2   select 111,'A1' from dual union all
  3   select 111,'A5' from dual union all
  4   select 112,'A3' from dual union all
  5   select 113,'A4' from dual union all
  6   select 111,'A6' from dual union all
  7   select 112,'A8' from dual union all
  8   select 113,'A9' from dual
  9  )
 10  select userid
 11       , card_no
 12    from ( select userid
 13                , rtrim(res, ',') as card_no
 14                , rn
 15             from t1
 16            model
 17            partition by (userid)
 18            dimension by (row_number() over(partition by userid 
 19                                            order by card_no) as rn)
 20            measures(card_no, cast(null as varchar2(255)) as res)
 21            rules(
 22               res[any] order by rn desc = card_no[cv()] || ',' || res[cv() + 1]
 23            )
 24         ) s
 25  where s.rn = 1
 26  order by userid
 27  ;
```

Result:

```
 USERID  CARD_NO
 ----------------
 111     A1,A5,A6
 112     A3,A8 
 113     A4,A9
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5d391/1)

[Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10736/sqlmodel.htm#sthref1760) about model clause

Moreover, [there are](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) plenty of other string aggregation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LISTAGG` function as of Oracle 11g R2.

e.g.

```
SELECT deptno
, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees
FROM   emp
GROUP  BY
deptno;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid, wm_concat(card_no) from table_name group by userid
```

Comment: Bear in mind usage of wm_concat is not recommended, as this is an undocumented function.. If you are gonna use it in a production environment use LISTAGG as given by devek...