# Collecting into VARRAY inside SQL statement

Tags: oracle, group-concat, varray

I have the following SQL query :

```
SELECT ID, OC_YEAR FROM ACCOUNTS;
```

This query returns the following resultset:

```
       ID       |     OC_YEAR          
------------------------------------    
       10            2006
       10            2007
       10            2008
       11            2006
       11            2008
```

On the other hand I have a custom type

```
 create TYPE IDS AS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER(5);
```

And finally I have a function that recieves 2 parameters of type IDS and NUMBER. Is there a way I can collect ID columns into an IDS variable grouping them under the OC_YEAR column and send these two arguments to my function. To make it clearer I need to group the resultset of the above query like this:

```
(10,11):2006
(10):2007
(10,11):2008
```

Not exactly but something similar to GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL.

Comment: As I said, I'm not looking for an exact equivalent of GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: The answer is still pretty much the same ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate of [this one:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql)

**If you have Oracle 10G:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUE ( INPUT_VAL IN NUMBER )
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    RETURN_TEXT VARCHAR2 ( 10000 ) := NULL;
BEGIN
    FOR X IN ( SELECT
                  ID
            FROM
                  ACCOUNTS
            WHERE
                  OC_YEAR = INPUT_VAL )
    LOOP
        RETURN_TEXT :=
               RETURN_TEXT
            || ','
            || X.ID;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN LTRIM ( RETURN_TEXT,
                ',' );
END;
/
```

So, you can do like:

```
SELECT
      GET_COMMA_SEPARATED_VALUE ( ID ),
      OC_YEAR
FROM
      ACCOUNTS;
```

**If you have got oracle 11g, you can use listagg :**

```
SELECT
      LISTAGG ( OC_YEAR,
              ', ' )
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID),
      OC_YEAR
FROM
      ACCOUNTS
GROUP BY
      OC_YEAR;
```

Comment: I think there is a mistake in your 10g Code. Shouldn't the function expect the `OC_YEAR` as a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11.2 introduced function [LISTAGG](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030), which does the same like GROUP_CONCAT. If you don't have Oracle 11.2 available you have to encapsulate it in a function.