# How do I find user with more keys in a table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
SELECT bau.username, cc.key
FROM ba_users bau
INNER JOIN billings ba
  ON ba.id = bau.billing_account_id
INNER JOIN accc_once_only_cc_map acooc
  ON acooc.billing_account_id = ba.id
INNER JOIN account_components_map acm
  on acooc.account_component_id = acm.account_component_id
INNER JOIN cuoffers cuo
  ON cuo.id = acm.customized_offer_id
INNER JOIN charges cc
  ON cc.key = acooc.charge_cluster_key;
```

result is for example

```
USERNAME        KEY
1182925980_0    RT_FEE
1182926277_0    RT_FEE
1182926574_0    RT_FEE
1182924785_0    RT_FEE
1182925980_0    RT_FEE2
1182923514_0    RT_FEE
1182932481_0    RT_FEE
1182936581_0    RT_FEE
1182941631_0    RT_FEE
```

now I would like to found which user has more then one key and print out the user with keys.

like:

```
1182925980_0
```

has keys

```
RT_FEE and RT_FEE2
```

How to do this with plsql?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part (finding users with > 1 key)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT bau.username, cc.key
  FROM ba_users bau
  INNER JOIN billings ba
    ON ba.id = bau.billing_account_id
  INNER JOIN accc_once_only_cc_map acooc
    ON acooc.billing_account_id = ba.id
  INNER JOIN account_components_map acm
    on acooc.account_component_id = acm.account_component_id
  INNER JOIN cuoffers cuo
    ON cuo.id = acm.customized_offer_id
  INNER JOIN charges cc
    ON cc.key = acooc.charge_cluster_key
)
SELECT username, COUNT(*)
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY username
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The second part of your query (showing a list of all keys projected in a single column) will will depend on whether you can use [listagg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql) or not.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT bau.username, cc.key
  FROM ba_users bau
  INNER JOIN billings ba
    ON ba.id = bau.billing_account_id
  INNER JOIN accc_once_only_cc_map acooc
    ON acooc.billing_account_id = ba.id
  INNER JOIN account_components_map acm
    on acooc.account_component_id = acm.account_component_id
  INNER JOIN cuoffers cuo
    ON cuo.id = acm.customized_offer_id
  INNER JOIN charges cc
    ON cc.key = acooc.charge_cluster_key
)
SELECT username, LISTAGG(key, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY key) the_keys
  FROM CTE
  GROUP BY username
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT username,key,COUNT(*)
FROM ba_users
GROUP BY username,key
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This should display the username with more than one key, hope this helps.

Comment: Do you need vote? your answer is wrong,how you get votes for wrong answer?

Comment: Grouping by username AND key will only show instances where the same user has the **same** key more than once.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT username,COUNT(username) FROM
(SELECT bau.username, cc.key
FROM ba_users bau
INNER JOIN billings ba
  ON ba.id = bau.billing_account_id
INNER JOIN accc_once_only_cc_map acooc
  ON acooc.billing_account_id = ba.id
INNER JOIN account_components_map acm
  on acooc.account_component_id = acm.account_component_id
INNER JOIN cuoffers cuo
  ON cuo.id = acm.customized_offer_id
INNER JOIN charges cc
  ON cc.key = acooc.charge_cluster_key)t1 
GROUP BY username
HAVING(COUNT(username) > 1);
```