# Two wm_concat in a single query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Consider a table as follows -

```
TABLE DB.TEMP_TABLE
------------------------------------------  
field1        field2           field3
------------------------------------------  
1             10                100  
1             20                200  
1             30                300  
1             40                400
2             10                100  
2             20                200
```

I need to concatenate `field2` and `field3` on the basis of `field1`. The desired result should look like this -

```
DESIRED RESULT
------------------------------------------  
field1        field2           field3
------------------------------------------
1             10,20,30,40      100,200,300,400
2             10,20            100,200
```

The query I am using for this query is given below -

```
SELECT field1,
  wm_concat(field2),
  wm_concat(field3)
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY field1;
```

Here is the result I am getting -

```
------------------------------------------  
field1        field2           field3
------------------------------------------
1             10,20,40,30      100,400,300,200
2             10,20            100,200
```

Please suggest me a working query and if possible please explain this behaviour.

I am using `Oracle 10g` and have also tried using `xmlagg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH or XMLAGG as alternatives to WM_CONCAT (unsupported). An example for SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH is found in an Oracle Forum discussion [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/983341?tstart=0). I created a SQL Fiddle using XMLAGG [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15ba6/6).

Also, you can use the ORDER BY clause (as shown in the examples), if you need the values concatenated in a certain order.

References:

[LISTAGG alternative in 10g](http://www.dautkhanov.com/2010/08/listagg-alternative-in-10g.html)

[Related Question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql)

Comment: According to your fiddle, the fields are always sorted.
Consider entries like `1|20|300` and `1|30|200`. The result in this case will be `1|20,30|200,300`. The desired one is `1|20,30|300,200`. A fiddle for the same is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d22d/1)

Comment: I understand that you want field3 in the same order as field2. So, I modified the fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4d22d/2) to order field3 by field2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

`wm_concat` is not documented/supported by Oracle, so there is no guarantee that it will be around in the future. You can use sub-queries for that. If you prefer using a function, you can create your own function and use it similar to `wm_concat`. [Check this link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

Comment: As I have already mentioned, I have also used `xmlagg`, but still getting the same result.

Comment: OK, implement your own function. The link I mentioned does most of the work for you.

Comment: @RacilHilan `wm_concat` has indeed been removed from 12c.  Which is a little surprising, I thought `wm_concat` was some sort of common-law feature by now.

Comment: @jonearles Yes, you got it right, and like "common-law" you don't need a divorce to end it ;), and that's what 12c did.