# ANSI sql to dynamically convert rows into column data

Tags: sql, oracle, ansi-sql

I have a dynamic input data as below

```
   Id  val
   --- -----
    10  A
    10  B
    11  A
    11  B
    11  C
    .   .
    .   .
```

I need to print it following order.

```
    Id  Val
   ---- ----
    10  A,B
    11  A,B,C
```

I need to write single query to convert above data without using any inbuilt functions.

**My try:** I can try this out by populating data in to some temporary data and update records as below.

Step 1: try loading into temp data with unique id column alone and val as null as below.

```
create table temp as (select id, null as val from table group by id) with data;
```

Step 2: Update as follows.

```
update temp t2 
set val=(case when t2.val is null then t1.val else t1.val || ',' t2.val end) from 
(select val from table t1 where t1.val= t2.val) t1
```

Now, temp table will have above output...
**But all i need is , is there anyway to bring this output without using Temp table (single query)..**

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string. Next time, try google

Comment: The use of `||` for string concatenation strongly suggests Oracle.  I am removing the other database tags.  Of course, the OP can add the correct flags, if this is not reasonable.

Comment: @Jaques : Thanks. but i need ANSI standard format. they are using some inbuilt function to achieve this.,.

Comment: Why do want ANSI Standard?You`ll use it on multiple dbs?

Comment: @Mihai : Yes. I need generic query which can run on any RDBMS

Comment: @Mihai . . . The question is more like:  "Why do you want ANSI standard?  No database supports *that*."  Okay, increasingly the standard and databases are moving closer in many areas, so that is a tad too cynical.

Answer (score 0):

can try this:

```
select ID, group_concat(distinct value) as value
from table
group by ID
```

Comment: what is that group_concat ?

Comment: okay i see you've tagged wrong tags. above code works for mysql. here similar to group_concat in oracle:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-like-group-concat-of-mysql

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you would use `listagg()`:

```
select id, listagg(val, ',') within group (order by val)
from table t
group by id
order by id;
```

There is not ANSI standard mechanism for doing this operation, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks gordon.. but i dont want to use any inbuilt function. like listagg.. is there any common ANSI standard SQL for the same ?

Comment: one more thing, do you think, whatever i have done using `UPDATE` query is correct ?

Comment: What is the problem with my query using temp table ?

Comment: Please help me to find what is the wrong with my query using temp table. I need to understand if there is any problem. Then i will also use inbuilt query you suggested

Comment: @logan . . . Is there a maximum number of elements in a row?

Comment: No. It can have `n` number of rows and any kind of `val`