# Want to get one row when doing select distinct with inner join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Let's assume I have two tables (A and B):

```
A:
|   ID   | column1   |   B_ID   |  column2 | ... | column x |
|   1    | xxx       |   25     | xxxx...

B:
|  ID    | B_ID |  C    |  column 1  | ...   | column x|
|  2     | 25   |   55  |   xxxxxxx
|  3     | 25   |   66  |   xxxxxxx (data in all other columns are the same,
```

only C column differs)
 and I do inner join on them (using B_ID).

Because in table B there are two matching rows for inner join, I get two rows as a result. This happens even when using DISTINCT because data in column C differs. Is there some way to somehow join differing values of C in new value (like "55,66") or to put C value 66 in another column (like C_1) so I can have only one row as a result?

Comment: Always try to include your rdbms tag for sql questions `SqlServer`, `MySql`?. Some functions arent available on all databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any function in oracle similar to group\_concat in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql) There you have sql server, mysql and oracle versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the SQL version you're using:
Oracle - look at STRING_AGG() function on asktom.com if prior to Oracle 11G, built-in as LISTAGG() afterwards.
mysql- look at group_concat() 
sql server - [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
A T1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT ID,B_ID,GROUP_CONCAT(C),column1,column2,column3,..,columnx
FROM B 
GROUP BY B_ID) T2 ON T2.B_ID=T1.B_ID
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: this is only for mysql