# Group concat Values separate with other rows as a name in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`flim_category_name` SEPARATOR '*') 
`flim_category_name`,country, GROUP_CONCAT(`flim_video` SEPARATOR '*') flim_video,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`flim_video_images` SEPARATOR '*') flim_video_images FROM 
  flim_management_table GROUP BY `country` limit 0,1
```

In this query I am getting the table structure like this

```
flim_category_name    country     flim_video                                       flim_video_images
Guru*Mersal*Aadi      India    ww.com,ww.com,ww.com* ww.com,ww.com,ww.com* ,,,     217953157.jpg,,,,,,,,,*,,,,,,,,,
```

I need to separator with start instead of separate row  like this

```
flim1 flim2   flim3    country     flim_video1             flim_video2        flim_video3   images1        image2     image 3
Guru  Mersal   Aadi      India    ww.com,ww.com,ww.com  ww.com,ww.com,ww.com       ,,,    217953157.jpg,,,  ,,,,,     ,,,,,
```

I need to structure the table like this.

Comment: what have your tried so far..?

Comment: Mysql and Oracle DBs are different..which one are you using..?

Comment: There is no answer to this. How can we know what you mean by "concatenate the column"? What column?

Comment: you can achieve something near your result  by mysql's group_concat

Comment: [normalise the db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), this is terrible structure

Comment: I Corrected the question is there is they way to separate with columns in another row.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the best I could come up with was this.

```
 WITH f AS
(
       SELECT 'Ghajini'             film_category_name ,
              'INDIA'               country ,
              'IMG1.jpg,iMAGE2.JPG' flim_images,
              'WW.COM,WW.COM,WW.COM' flim_url 
       FROM   dual
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'dIWALE'              film_category_name ,
              'INDIA'               country ,
              'IMG1.jpg,iMAGE2.JPG' flim_images,
              'WW.COM,WW.COM'       flim_url
       FROM   dual
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'gURU'                film_category_name ,
              'SOUTH AFRICA'        country,
              'IMG1.jpg,iMAGE2.JPG' flim_images,
              'WW.COM,WW.COM'       flim_url
       FROM   dual ), f2 AS
(
         SELECT   f.* ,
                  Row_number() over (PARTITION BY country ORDER BY ROWNUM ) rn
         FROM     f ), f3 AS
(
         SELECT   Listagg(film_category_name,',') within GROUP ( ORDER BY ROWNUM ) over ( PARTITION BY country ) film_category_name ,
                  country ,
                  flim_images,
                  flim_url,
                  rn
         FROM     f2 )
SELECT *
FROM   f3 pivot ( max(flim_images) AS flim_images_row  ,
                  max(flim_url)    AS flim_url FOR rn IN (1,2) ) p
ORDER BY film_category_name;
```

Output is something like this:

```
FILM_CATEGORY_NAME    COUNTRY           1_FLIM_IMAGES_ROW    1_FLIM_URL             2_FLIM_IMAGES_ROW   2_FLIM_URL
Ghajini,dIWALE         INDIA            IMG1.jpg,iMAGE2.JPG  WW.COM,WW.COM,WW.COM   IMG1.jpg,iMAGE2.JPG WW.COM,WW.COM
gURU                   SOUTH AFRICA     IMG1.jpg,iMAGE2.JPG  WW.COM,WW.COM   -
```

If you do not know the number of rows you will have for each `country` , then your only option is to generate and execute the query dynamically using dynamic SQL.I do not however recommend it because the structure and design of your table is inefficient for any data extraction. You need to restructure your components and create separate tables wherever required to store and retrieve useful data.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) function of Mysql:

```
select group_concat(Film_category_name), Country, group_concat(flim_images),group_concat(flim_url) from table group by country
```

and for oracle check this:
[Is there any function in oracle similar to group_concat in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql)