# I am trying to create a query to bring data from one table to another table as described below?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

```
SELECT EL_VALUES_FIELD1
     , EL_VALUES_FIELD2
     , EL_VALUES_FIELD4
     , SUM (EL_VALUES_FIELD5) 
FROM DATA_FORM_VALUES_919906 
GROUP 
    BY EL_VALUES_FIELD1
     , EL_VALUES_FIELD2
     , EL_VALUES_FIELD4
```

Image 1 is the source table and Image 2 is the destination image

[image: source]

[image: destination]

Comment: Do you want to Insert the tableA rows into tableB ? Or do you want to show both tables' rows in a single view ?

Comment: ... and I think the "jquery" tag is probably not what you were thinking.

Comment: @BaSsGaz I want to insert table A rows into table B

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Following query will get the job done:

```
select field1,
       field2,
       Group_concat(field3 order by field3 desc separator ',') as keyfield_3,
       field4,
       sum(amount) as amount
from table
group by field1,field2,field4;
```

Above query will only work for **MySQL** and only display result. If you want to insert these values in another table then do the following:

```
Insert into tablename(keyfield1,keyfield2,keyfield3,keyfield4,amount)
select field1,
           field2,
           Group_concat(field3 order by field3 desc separator ',') as keyfield_3,
           field4,
           sum(amount) as amount
    from table
    group by field1,field2,field4;
```

If you want to achieve same task in Oracle, you should use `LISTAGG()` instead of `Group_concat()`

**Oracle:**

```
Insert into tablename(keyfield1,keyfield2,keyfield3,keyfield4,amount)
select field1,
           field2,
           LISTAGG(field3,',') WITHIN GROUP (order by field3 desc),
           field4,
           sum(amount) as amount
    from table
    group by field1,field2,field4;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL, use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine the values from `field3`.

```
INSERT INTO destination (keyfield1, keyfield2, keyfield3, keyfield4, amount)
SELECT field1, field2, GROUP_CONCAT(field3), field4, SUM(amount)
FROM source
GROUP BY field1, field2, field4
```

See [Is there any function in oracle similar to group_concat in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql) if you're actually using Oracle.