# Display rows with common element in a horizontal format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Table data set:

```
SSN        ID  F_NAME  L_NAME
000000000  1   JANE    DOE
123456789  2   PETE    PETER
123456789  3   JOHN    SHAW
234567890  4   ALAN    DAVID
234567890  5   MAY     APRI
345677891  6   JUNE    ALYSSA
456789123  7   LISA    LINH
567891234  8   HAL     LEY
567891234  9   DEREK   LI
567891234  10  JIM     JAMES
```

From the data set above, my intention is to identify IDs/demographics with same SSNs and list horizontally all the names and the results as below. We are also interested in the count of unique IDs associated with each SSN.

```
SSN       COUNT ID  F_NAME  L_NAME ID_2 F_NAME_2 L_NAME_2 ID_3 F_NAME_3 L_NAME_3
123456789 2     2   PETE    PETER  3    JOHN     SHAW
234567889 2     4   ALAN    DAVID  5    MAY      APRI
567891234 3     8   HAL     LEY    9    DEREK    LI       10   JIM      JAMES
```

Help?

Comment: PIVOT or XMLPIVOT

Comment: @lad2025 thanks for the suggestion, however, I'm having difficulty implementing it with either. could you kindly show how you'd implement with either PIVOT or XMLPIVOT to obtain results as described above?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use listagg in the following fashion, and you can add the unique ID as well:

```
create table demographics(
ssn number(9),
id number(12),
f_name varchar2(50),
l_name varchar2(50));


insert into demographics values(000000000,  1,   'JANE',    'DOE');
insert into demographics values(123456789,  2,   'PETE',    'PETER');
insert into demographics values(123456789,  3,   'JOHN',    'SHAW');
insert into demographics values(234567890,  4,   'ALAN',    'DAVID');
insert into demographics values(234567890,  5,   'MAY',     'APRI');
insert into demographics values(345677891,  6,   'JUNE',    'ALYSSA');
insert into demographics values(456789123,  7,   'LISA',    'LINH');
insert into demographics values(567891234,  8,   'HAL',     'LEY');
insert into demographics values(567891234,  9,   'DEREK',   'LI');
insert into demographics values(567891234,  10,  'JIM',     'JAMES');

SELECT ssn, count(ssn) as count, LISTAGG(f_name || ' ' || l_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f_name || ' ' || l_name) "Names"
FROM demographics
group by ssn;



SSN COUNT   Names
0   1   JANE DOE
123456789   2   JOHN SHAW, PETE PETER
234567890   2   ALAN DAVID, MAY APRI
345677891   1   JUNE ALYSSA
456789123   1   LISA LINH
567891234   3   DEREK LI, HAL LEY, JIM JAMES
```

Comment: thanks! as i have a large data set, this does not seem to work also due to the 'ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long'. Kindly have a similar implementation with the PIVOT?

Answer (score 1):

See more information on pivot [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot) as per @lad2025's advice

Depending on what format is allowable to you, a quick solution I would use would be the `listagg` function in [SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql) which is similar to MySQL's `group_concat` such as

```
SELECT SSN,
       count(*),
       LISTAGG(ID, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID),
       LISTAGG(F_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY F_NAME)
FROM table GROUP BY SSN HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

would result in

```
123456789 2     2,3      PETE, JOHN    
234567889 2     4,5      ALAN, MAY   
567891234 3     8,9,10   HAL, DEREK, JIM
```

---

Alternatively, you could identify all rows with duplicate SSNs - this would avoid using `pivot` and keep your result in the same relational format

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE SSN in (SELECT SSN from table group by SSN having count(*) > 1);
```

would return all rows with duplicate SSNs:

```
SSN        ID  F_NAME  L_NAME
123456789  2   PETE    PETER
123456789  3   JOHN    SHAW
234567890  4   ALAN    DAVID
234567890  5   MAY     APRI
567891234  8   HAL     LEY
567891234  9   DEREK   LI
567891234  10  JIM     JAMES
```

Comment: thanks @Anna. I get a 'ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long' with this implementation. Seems while it may work under certain conditions, there's the limit

Comment: @DaveJabbz That is because you probably have duplicate SSNs with many people associated with them. I added an alternative to my answer.