# Sql query to Select data for same date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table that contains assignment_id, student_id, assignment_name and assignment_date. I have to write a SQL query to get list of students who submitted 2 assignments on same date. I also need assignment_name and assignment_date in output. I am stuck with which query can I write to get this data. Any help would be highly appreciated

[image: Image of the data]

Comment: (1) You should show your attempted query.  (2) You should tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am using Oracle SQL. I am very new to SQL queries and completely stuck with where to start from

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am using Oracle SQL. I am very new to SQL queries and completely stuck with where to start from

Comment: Hint : `Group by student_id,training_date` + `Having`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

**In MYSQL Query**

```
  SELECT student_id, training_date, GROUP_CONCAT(assignment_name)
     FROM
   table_name
   GROUP BY student_id, training_date HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

"[Is there any function in oracle similar to group_concat in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql)" might help you to replace GROUP_CONCAT in **oracle SQL**

Comment: Hardik, thank you so much for your help. But GROUP_CONCAT is giving me an error. I think it doesnt work in Oracle

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.student_id = t.student_id and 
                    t1.training_date = t.training_date and 
                    t1.assignment_id <> t.assignment_id
             );
```