# Concat results from one column

Tags: java, string, oracle, select, group-by

How to concat results from column in Oracle SQL. same function as GROUP_CONCAT().

I have data like this

[image]

I want to get the result like this.

[image]

I already used listagg()

`SELECT LISTAGG(S.MEASURE_WEIGHT, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S.Plan_id)`

result are:

[image]

Without zeroes :(
can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16771086/is-there-any-function-in-oracle-similar-to-group-concat-in-mysql Check this out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    measure_id,
    max(case when plan_id = 1050 then measure_weight else 0 end)
        || '/'
        || max(case when plan_id = 1055 then measure_weight else 0 end) weight
from mytable
group by measure_id
```

Comment: I already used that and the result are:
53 | 4.9/4.5 ------ 
82 | 5 ------ 
81 | 5

I need it to be like this
53 | 4.9/4.5  ------ 
82 | 5/0  ------ 
81 | 0/5

Comment: @VanessaLaineGorre: I gave a second look at your question and came up with another solution. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this query using two subqueries may work:

```
SELECT
    measure_id,
    TO_CHAR(NVL((
        SELECT weight FROM table t1 
        WHERE t1.measure_id = t.measure_id AND t1.plan_id = t.min_id AND t.min_id = 1050), 0)) 
    || '/' ||
    TO_CHAR(NVL((
        SELECT weight FROM table t2 
        WHERE t2.measure_id = t.measure_id AND t2.plan_id = t.max_id AND t.max_id = 1055), 0))
FROM (
    SELECT measure_id, min(plan_id) min_id, max(plan_id) max_id
    FROM table
    GROUP BY measure_id
) t;
```