# Distinct Column, but duplicate other columhs

Tags: plsql, coldfusion

I am trying to modify a PL/SQL query that pulls a distinct list for a ColdFusion dropdown, which in turn runs a query for a filter based on what was chosen in the dropdown. The problem is, the distinct list has multiple entries as there are a couple of entries that map to 2 different short descriptions.

Here is an example of my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.LONG_DESCR,  O.OPTION_ID,O.SHORT_DESCR 
FROM OPTION         O   
JOIN GROUP      G   ON      o.GROUP_ID = G.GROUP_ID
WHERE O.SHORT_DESCR IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F')
ORDER BY O.LONG_DESCR
```

I do not need to join to GROUP in this query, but that is what they had in the previous query I need to update. What happens is when this is ran, it shows an output of something similar to this:

```
Agent 1   1   'A' 
Agent 1   3   'C'
Agent 2   2   'B'
Agent 3   4   'D'
Agent 3   6   'F'
Agent 4   5   'E'
```

Notice that short description A and C have the same Long Description and short description D and F have the same long description.

The dropdown only looks at long description and outputs

```
Agent 1
Agent 1
Agent 2
Agent 3
Agent 3
Agent 4
```

We need the dropdown to just have Agent 1, 2, 3, and 4 and no duplicates but if they choose, for instance, agent 1 then the query will filter out to just anything with Short Description of 'A' and 'C'.

Maybe I should be thinking about how to do it in ColdFusion but I am not too familiar with that, yet. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's quite likely that the option_id is the most relevent field to the subsequent query.  That being the case, you have to ensure that you offer all relevent values to the user for selection.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, you could [use string functions to build a csv list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822700/building-a-comma-separated-list-of-values-in-an-oracle-sql-statement) of all id's corresponding to *each* unique description:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(OPTION_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OPTION_ID) AS OPTION_ID_LIST
      , LONG_DESCR
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY LONG_DESCR
  ORDER BY LONG_DESCR
 ;
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f603e/3/0)

Then use the list of id's as the `<select>` list "value" and the description the "text":

```
   <select name="optionID">
      <cfoutput query="yourQuery">
         <option value="#OPTION_ID_LIST#">#LONG_DESCR#</option>         
      </cfoutput>
   </select>
```

When the form is submitted, you will have a list of id's which can be used in a `WHERE IN (...)` clause:

```
    WHERE SomeColumnID IN 
         (   
             <cfqueryparam value="#form.optionID#"   
                cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" 
                list="true">
         )
```

Depending on the relationship of GROUP_ID here (which is not clear from the question), there may be other options as well. *If* each description corresponds to a single GROUP_ID, then simply use GROUP_ID as the select list value, and use the group id in your filter instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to select the distinct long_description, only select the distinct long_description. Trying to select those other fields is resulting in your duplicates.

Comment: I understand that. But I need the other fields in order to query off of. There is another query that uses the short_descr field to query off of.

Comment: Use a query of queries (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff0.html) to pull out the distinct values, or split it into two different queries. Which makes more sense depends on your data.