# Transform SQL Rows into Comma-Separated values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

How can you produce a comma-separated values from list of return rows in SQL without creating a function?  Need to remove duplicates and null or with 'None' as the value.

Example: `select name from student;`

The result :

```
         NAME         
        ------
        Zed
        Charlo
        None
        Charlo
        Dionn
        Ansay
```

Desired output :

```
              Name
             -------
             Zed,Charlo,Dionn,Ansay
```

Comment: is this isn't a dupe I'd be surprised.

Comment: first hit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle

Comment: BTW: if you have any Oracle question, prefix your internet search with "Tom kyte"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ad65/2

```
select 
  listagg(name, ',') 
    within group (order by id) as list 
from student
```

Comment: Full disclosure: sqlfiddle.com is my site.

Comment: @JakeFeasel SQL Fiddle looks pretty neat!

Comment: @Sathya thanks, I hope people here find it a useful tool for answering these sorts of questions.