# Oracle concatenation of columns with comma

Tags: sql, database, oracle, concatenation, string-aggregation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Could some one please tell me how to achieve the following?

Table:

```
efforts_id        cycle_name      release_name 
123               quarter         march 
123               half            april 
123               full            april
124               quarter         may
```

My expected output:

```
efforts_id        cycle_name            release_name 
123               quarter,half,full     march,april
124               quarter               may
```

I am a beginner in oracle so not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm) to perform this task.  The other answers don't remove any of the duplicate values, to remove the duplicates, you can use something similar to this:

```
select c.efforts_id, 
  c.cycle_name,
  listagg(r.release_name, ', ') within group (order by c.efforts_id) as release_name
from
(
  select efforts_id,
    listagg(cycle_name, ', ') within group (order by efforts_id) as cycle_name
  from yourtable
  group by efforts_id
) c
inner join
(
  select distinct efforts_id, release_name
  from yourtable
) r
  on c.efforts_id = r.efforts_id
group by c.efforts_id, c.cycle_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5bb00/46)

Comment: @Jeevan you are welcome, would can probably clean this up a bit using a `with` clause instead of the sub-select, whichever is your preference

Comment: hmm ok.. i am not sure how to do that. (I'm new to oracle..brand new :)). I will go with your answer for now.

Comment: need help pls.. i want to do the duplicate removal on both cycle_name and release_name columns.. i tried few things but does not seem to work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/430ee/15 please help

Comment: @Jeevan please check this demo --  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/430ee/22

Answer (score 7):

What you need is "string aggregation". Tim Hall's excellent site shows the alternatives you have depending on the exact version of Oracle you have: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php

In 11gR2 (current at time of writing), you should use the listagg function:

```
select
  efforts_id,
  listagg(cycle_name, ',') within group (order by cycle_name) as cycle_name,
  listagg(release_name, ',') within group (order by release_name) as release_name
from my_table
group by efforts_id;
```

Note that the use of the wm_concat function is unsupported by Oracle...

Comment: +1, and remember that listagg is limited by 4000 bytes.

Comment: Because it's a varchar, not a clob. Rumours are that in Oracle 12c -- due around the end of the year -- will have varchars up to 32767 in the database just like in PL/SQL...

Comment: @ErkanHaspulat 4000 char, surely?!

Comment: Thank you... Just one problem.. The output comes like this. Release _name for 123 is march,april,april... how to avoid duplicate april?

Comment: You can `distinct` your data before aggregating it. You'll probably need a subquery or a with clause.

Comment: @Colin'tHart
Yes, and not 4000 chars 4000 bytes. Check this out:

    `select listagg('a', '') within group (order by 1) 
    from all_objects
    where rownum < 4002`

You get: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

And with this:

    `select listagg('ğ', '') within group (order by 1) 
    from all_objects
    where rownum < 2002`

You get the same: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`

That's because 'ğ' is stored in 2 bytes, and 'a' is only 1 byte.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Oracle 11g R2, then LISTAGG is the preferred way to do it:

```
SELECT efforts_id,
    LISTAGG(cycle_name) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY cycle_name),
    LISTAGG(release_name) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY cycle_name)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY efforts_id
```

If not, [this article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) shows the alternative ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Through the [WM_concat](http://psoug.org/definition/WM_CONCAT.htm) function (and `GROUP BY` of course)

```
SELECT efforts_id, wm_concat(cycle_name), wm_concat(release_name)
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY efforts_id
```

Hmmm, just found this:

> Note that **WM_CONCAT** is *undocumented and unsupported* by Oracle, meaning it should not be used in production systems
>   The **[LISTAGG](http://psoug.org/definition/LISTAGG.htm)** function, which can produce the same output as **WM_CONCAT** is both documented and supported by Oracle.