# Create comma seperated list for joined table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two table 
`'ga_mise_en_stage' alias 'm'`

`and 'ga_annee_academique' alias 'ac'`, and

on `'ga_annee_academique'` there is `foreign key that point to 'ga_mise_en_stage'`.

It is difficult for me to make query to retrive m.code_mise_stage, m.Libelle and all ac.annee_academique that related to m.code_mise_stage in the same ligne

`schema for ga_mise_en_stage  : code_mise_enstage(pk), libelle`

`schema for ga_annee_academique : code_annee_academique(pk), annee_academique, code_mise_en_stage(fk)`

I want comma seperated result for 
`m.*, "ac.annee_academique, ..."`

Comment: Can you provide a proper schema?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking

Comment: Can you also provide your current query?  Some of us find the question as stated a little confusing.

Comment: U should give us the definition of the 2 tables with the fields noumns...

Answer (score 1):

You need to join on your foreign key..

```
select m.code_mise_stage, m.Libelle, ac.annee_academique, ac.*
FROM ga_annee_academique ac
inner join ga_mise_en_stage m
on ac.code_mise_en_stage = m.code_mise_enstage
```

**EDIT:**
Comma seperated list - This works only on SQL Server

```
SELECT  m.code_mise_stage, m.Libelle, STUFF((SELECT  ',' + ac.annee_academique
            FROM ga_annee_academique ac
            WHERE  m.code_mise_enstage=ac.code_mise_en_stage
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr
FROM ga_mise_en_stage m
GROUP BY m.code_mise_stage, m.Libelle
```

**EDIT:** Using system table to make this example more generic.

```
select t.TABLE_NAME, STUFF
(
    (select ', ' + c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME FOR XML PATH(''))
    , 1,1, ''
)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t where TABLE_NAME = 'ga_mise_en_stage'
```

Here is a documentation on [XML PATH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189885.aspx)

In this example, query below returns XML as a string where each element is seperated by ',' which is used as an XML element.

```
select ', ' + c.COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c 
        WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = 'FormulaMetrics_tbl' FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: thanks Mr Shantanu, but iwant that 'ac.annee_academique' that related to specific 'm.code_mise_stage' be concatained

Comment: i test your last answers, there is missing right parathense that i don't find it, can you explain please 'for xml path'

Comment: This works only on sql server

Comment: oh no, i use oracle :/, but thank you Mr Gupta.

Comment: You can search for comma seperated list in Oracle. check if this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle
Updated your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Mr Shantanu, it's done !

Answer (score 0):

the Query will be like that :

```
 select M.LIBELLE_STAGE, M.CODE_MISE_STAGE, JOINATE.anneeAcademique from ga_mise_en_stage m
 inner join (select AC.CODE_MISE_EN_STAGE, listagg(AC.ANNEE_ACADEMIQUE, ',') within group (order by AC.CODE_MISE_EN_STAGE) as anneeAcademique from ga_annee_academique ac
  group by AC.CODE_MISE_EN_STAGE) joinate 
  on JOINATE.CODE_MISE_EN_STAGE = M.CODE_MISE_STAGE
```