# How to group multiple values into a single column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Given the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    T1."PN" as "Part Number",
    T2."QTY" as "Quantity",
    T2."BRANCH" AS "Location", T3."STOCK" as "Bin"
FROM 
    "XYZ"."PARTS" T1,
    "XYZ"."BALANCES" T2,
    "XYZ"."DETAILS" T3
WHERE (T2."PART_ID" = T1."PART_ID") AND (T3."PART_ID" = T1."PART_ID")
ORDER BY "Part Number" ASC, "Location" ASC
```

We get results such as

```
YZ-7-CA-080                 88  01  STOCK7
YZ-7-CA-080                 88  01  03482 
YZ-7-CA-080                 88  01  A8K2D
```

For location 01, there are 88 pieces of that part number YZ-7-CA-080 and they can be found in any of the 3 bins STOCK7, 03482, or A8K2D.
The location value refers to a common branch like a warehouse and the quantity is for the entire warehouse, not the bins.

I need to change the output so we can write out instead one entry with bins as a list

```
YZ-7-CA-080                 88  01  STOCK7,03482,A8K2D
```

So I am looking for a good way to do this refactoring of the results in SQL. I feel there should be a way to use a function or subquery or something like that and hoping there is a single multi-db solution but assume there could be a need for different solutions on different dbs. (Oracle is the primary solution we are trying to solve but secondary priority db we need this for is SQL Server).

Note: There are multiple locations per part number so its not enough to set distinct on the first column to reduce the multiple part number entries. There would be multiple of the same part number at location 02 also with the same issue.

Ideas?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` are you actually using?  Sounds like Oracle, if so, use `LISTAGG`...

Comment: Oracle first and primary yes, but we also are building a connector for SQL Server to do similar later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For older versions, I guess **WM_CONCAT** would work. Modifying Gordon Linoff's query:

```
SELECT T1."PN" as "Part Number", max(T2."QTY") as "Quantity", T2."BRANCH" AS "Location",
       WM_CONCAT(T3."STOCK") as Bins
FROM "XYZ"."PARTS" T1 JOIN
     "XYZ"."BALANCES" T2
     ON T2."PART_ID" = T1."PART_ID" JOIN
     "XYZ"."DETAILS" T3
     ON T3."PART_ID" = T1."PART_ID"
GROUP BY t1.PN, t2.Branch
ORDER BY "Part Number", "Location";
```

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/470663/3492139) link for an alternate approach: Including the answer in the link for refernce:

```
create table countries ( country_name varchar2 (100));
insert into countries values ('Albania');
insert into countries values ('Andorra');
insert into countries values ('Antigua');


SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (country_name , ','), 2) csv
      FROM (SELECT country_name , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY country_name ) rn,
                   COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
              FROM countries)
     WHERE rn = cnt
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1;

CSV                                                                             
--------------------------
Albania,Andorra,Antigua
```

Comment: I've read that WM_CONCAT is unsupported and undocumented and other posts where people suggest not using it. What is the risk of using the command if it doesn't appear to have any issues when testing it? Does it put the database at risk in any way?

Comment: I tried your answer with the WM_CONCAT and it does work, thanks! Again, I wonder about any potential consequences to using the unsupported command.

Comment: The second portion of your answer that uses the substr doesn't make it clear to me how to combine the more complex table joins and selects for my current sql. Is that supposed to be a subquery to my sql?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Oracle using `listagg()`:

```
SELECT T1."PN" as "Part Number", max(T2."QTY") as "Quantity", T2."BRANCH" AS "Location",
       listagg(T3."STOCK") within group (order by  t3.stock) as Bins
FROM "XYZ"."PARTS" T1 JOIN
     "XYZ"."BALANCES" T2
     ON T2."PART_ID" = T1."PART_ID" JOIN
     "XYZ"."DETAILS" T3
     ON T3."PART_ID" = T1."PART_ID"
GROUP BY t1.PN, t2.Branch
ORDER BY "Part Number", "Location";
```

I also fixed the query to use proper explicit join syntax.

Comment: Looks promising... Thanks of the correction with the join. I tried setting it up and I am getting "Error Message:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" for some reason.

Comment: It is not obvious to me why that error would occur.

Comment: Ok, I will try to figure it out. I assume the BY BY in the GROUP BY is typo?

Comment: @Streamline . . . Yes, yes.

Comment: After some research, I believe the reason the error is shown is because LISTAGG is not available until 11gR2 and I confirmed our customer's database is 10g.

Comment: @Streamline . . . As Nishanti points out, `wm_concat()` is available in earlier versions.

Comment: thanks. Your solution seems the way to go if my customer wasn't using the older version of the database. I will see if Nishanti's use of wm_concat() solves it as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use substrings and subqueries, applying distinct in the first column

a similar technique is described here in this question: [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)