# Oracle SQL (no listagg) need to combine multiple rows into a single column

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am query multiple tables and need to combine all the values from a table called "NOTES" for a given ID.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT e.HR_NUMBER, s.SALES_ID, s.SALES_ID_TYPE, m.REGION_ID,
e.ADDED_DATE_TIME, e.TERMINATION_DATE, s.HOUSE_ACCOUNT, 
(SELECT t.NOTE FROM employee_note t WHERE e.hr_number = t.HR_NUMBER)
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN sales_id s
ON e.HR_NUMBER = s.HR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN market m
ON s.MARKET_ID = m.MARKET_ID
LEFT JOIN region r
ON m.REGION_ID = r.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN sales_id_type t
ON s.SALES_ID_TYPE = t.SALES_ID_TYPE
LEFT JOIN employee_note n
ON e.HR_NUMBER = n.HR_NUMBER
```

The problem is obviously it will not work when there are multiple notes for a given ID.

If I do the following sql:

```
SELECT e.HR_NUMBER, s.SALES_ID, s.SALES_ID_TYPE, m.REGION_ID,
e.ADDED_DATE_TIME, e.TERMINATION_DATE, s.HOUSE_ACCOUNT, n.NOTE
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN sales_id s
ON e.HR_NUMBER = s.HR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN market m
ON s.MARKET_ID = m.MARKET_ID
LEFT JOIN region r
ON m.REGION_ID = r.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN sales_id_type t
ON s.SALES_ID_TYPE = t.SALES_ID_TYPE
LEFT JOIN employee_note n
ON e.HR_NUMBER = n.HR_NUMBER
```

I get the following:

```
000000  E0019   XXX   XXX   23-JUN-10       N       NOTE 1
000000  E0019   XXX   XXX   23-JUN-10       N       NOTE 2
000000  E0019   XXX   XXX   23-JUN-10       N       NOTE 3
```

What I really need is:

```
000000  E0019   XXX   XXX   23-JUN-10       N       NOTE 1, NOTE 2, NOTE 3
```

I know you can use LISTAGG in oracle by my version doesn't support it.  Also I have tried several other answers on stackoverflow but I can't seem to get them to work for my query.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Before there was `list_agg()`, there was `wm_concat()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the below query using Common Table Expression [cte] would help:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT e.HR_NUMBER, s.SALES_ID, s.SALES_ID_TYPE, m.REGION_ID,
e.ADDED_DATE_TIME, e.TERMINATION_DATE, s.HOUSE_ACCOUNT, n.NOTE,
, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY NOTE ) rn,
COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN sales_id s
ON e.HR_NUMBER = s.HR_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN market m
ON s.MARKET_ID = m.MARKET_ID
LEFT JOIN region r
ON m.REGION_ID = r.REGION_ID
LEFT JOIN sales_id_type t
ON s.SALES_ID_TYPE = t.SALES_ID_TYPE
LEFT JOIN employee_note n
ON e.HR_NUMBER = n.HR_NUMBER
)
SELECT  HR_NUMBER, SALES_ID, SALES_ID_TYPE,REGION_ID,
ADDED_DATE_TIME, TERMINATION_DATE, HOUSE_ACCOUNT, 
SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (NOTE , ','), 2) csv
              FROM CTE  
     WHERE rn = cnt
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1;
```

I am basically trying to merge your query with a sample solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle)

Comment: Hey, thanks! It worked, however I am working with CLOBs and I reached limit error.  But when I ran it against my db with my changes it worked for some results.