# How to remove duplicates from comma separated list by regex in Oracle regexp_replace?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have

```
'VA - HRD 1, VA - HRD 1, VA - NOVA 1, VA - NOVA 1'
```

and want to get

```
'VA - HRD 1, VA - NOVA 1'
```

I am trying

```
regexp_replace( 'VA - HRD 1, VA - HRD 1, VA - NOVA 1, VA - NOVA 1' ,'([^,]+)(,\1)+', '\1')
```

but it doesn't remove all duplicates, it produces: `VA - HRD 1, VA - HRD 1, VA - NOVA 1`

Please help...

Comment: Assuming duplicates are grouped together ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+
```

Try this.This works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/8

The issue was `VA - HRD 1, VA - HRD 1`

```
                     ^  ^
```

The space here.You were not taking this into account as the first match has no space behid it.So inlcde `[ ]*` or `\s*` to make it accept.

Comment: Dude, what to do if string without spaces like : National,Carrier,Retail,Internal,National ?

Comment: @goodspeed we have used `[ ]*` `*` is for `0` t `more`.So it should work fine

Comment: and how to make it work for strings without spaces near comma?

Comment: @goodspeed `National,Carrier,Retail,Internal,National` here duplicates are not grouped together.So a new regex would be needed for this :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64022/discussion-between-goodspeed-and-vks).

Comment: i really dont know why this regex gets reposted all the time, it is wrong as it also matches '3,3' in '3773,3774,3830,3830'

Comment: @thg https://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/27

Comment: @vks thanks but regexp_replace('944,944,944,944,944,944','(?:^|,)([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+', '\1') does produce '944,944,944,944,944,944'

Comment: @thg it doesnt see here https://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9/28

Comment: Well my oracle 11 database does not, but ([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,) worked in the end. i think oracle 11 does not support conditional groups

Comment: @thg may be..didnt check d docs

Answer (score 0):

```
Select replace(REGEXP_REPLACE('1234567890,2220006789,2220006789,477-000-6789','([^,]+)(,[ ]*\1)+'),',,',',') 
As [columnName] From [tableName]
```

Comment: This answer wold be much improved if it included some explanation of what the code was doing. Whilst it may be correct "code only" doesn't necessarily help supplicants to achieve understanding.

Comment: This dosen't answer question he want to make a distinct list not actually remove duplicates..eg A, A, B, B -> A,B correct , A, B , B, C -> A, C incorrect answer .

Comment: This could be useful for something else but it does not answer the question.