# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB 00932. 00000

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, subquery, clob

I have column response_xml and request_xml which consist of large string. I have used substring function for this large string in order to fetch the SUBSCRIPTION_ID from response_xml and orderType from request_xml. The query is working fine. But now i want to put condition for this query such that it should only return SUBSCRIPTION_ID where orderType='NEW'. I used the below query but resulting an error as `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`. I think i need to cast column REQUEST_XML from clob to VARCHAR or XMLTYPE and then apply substring on this. But dont know how to do this. The error comes on where condition iw.order_type='NEW' . Here is my query:

```
select iw.order_type
    from (
       SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
       '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '') 
       AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML, '<ns7:orderType>\d+</ns7:orderType>'), '<ns7:orderType>', ''), '</ns7:orderType>', '') 
       AS order_type,
       CREATE_DATE
       FROM
       SOAP_MONITORING 
       where WEB_SERVICE_NAME='RatorWebShopService' and WEB_METHOD_NAME='placeShopOrder' 
    ) iw
    where iw.order_type='NEW'
    order by iw.CREATE_DATE desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column expression is being returned as a CLOB; you can cast it to a VARCHAR2:

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(REQUEST_XML, '<ns7:orderType>\d+</ns7:orderType>'),
    '<ns7:orderType>', ''), '</ns7:orderType>', '')
  AS VARCHAR(10)) AS order_type,
```

Where the size you specify should be large enough for the longest value you expect in that element. If you're expecting a string, though, having `\d+` in that regular expression isn't going to be right - if the actual value is NEW you'll get null back. You can use `'<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'`, for example.

You could wrap the `subscription_id` expression in a `to_number()` call as well if you want that to be more usable; you already know that's a numeric value from the `\d+` regular expression, where it does seem more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Alex its working. Just a small question. The SUBSCRIPTION_ID contains digits only so can i convert it to number instead of varchar for RESPONSE_XML ?

Comment: @Ajay - yes, I'd already edited to say you can use `to_number()` for that.

Comment: to_number(REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(RESPONSE_XML, '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>\d+</ax2130:id>'), 
   '<ax2147:subscriptions xsi:type="ax2127:SubscriptionDTO"><ax2130:id>', ''), '</ax2130:id>', '')) SUBSCRIPTION_ID                         Is it the correct i have wrriten to convert it to number ? and i have changed '<ns7:orderType>.+</ns7:orderType>'

Comment: Thanks Alex :) I will try to modify my query