# How to export oracle undetermined schemas using expdp

Tags: oracle, export, expdp

I want to export Oracle database, but not full and not determined schemas; for example schemas that their names like `'IAS%'` Or schema name like `'YS%'`

I have written this command:

```
Expdp admin/admin@orcl schemas like 'IAS%'  file=my_data.dmp directory=exp_dir
```

But i face error:

> invalid positional parameter value 'like'

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to run your export using that command. The Data Pump export utility (EXPDP) does not use regular `SQL`. You cannot use shorthand `SQL` commands in clauses - the clauses have to be defined in accordance to Oracle's documentation. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200), an example of the EXPDP schemas clause looks like the following:

`expdp hr DIRECTORY=dpump_dir1 DUMPFILE=expdat.dmp SCHEMAS=hr,sh,oe`

They have the schemas listed as comma separated values, and you will have to do something like this to perform your export. Instead of trying to use a query in the command itself, you could create a query that will return all of those schemas in comma separated format and simply copy and paste that list into the command.

To get that list, you could try running the following query:

```
select listagg(username,', ') within group(order by username) csv
  from all_users
  where username like 'IAS%';
```

This query uses the `listagg` [function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030). If you are using a version of Oracle that does not support `listagg`, you could use the following query to accomplish the same thing. I found this query on a separate [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468990/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-oracle), but it should work just fine:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (username , ','), 2) csv
      FROM (SELECT username , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY username ) rn,
                   COUNT (*) OVER () cnt
              FROM all_users where username like 'IAS%')
     WHERE rn = cnt
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY rn = PRIOR rn + 1;
```

Regardless of which query you use, you will now have a list of comma separated schemas that start with the string 'IAS'. For this example, let's say that list looks like `IAS_1, IAS_2, IAS_3`, etc. Your command would then change from:

`Expdp admin/admin@orcl schemas like 'IAS%'  file=my_data.dmp directory=exp_dir`

To something more like:

`Expdp admin/admin@orcl schemas=IAS_1,IAS_2,IAS_3  file=my_data.dmp directory=exp_dir`

If schemas are created and dropped often within this database, you could run the query to update the list of schemas that are impacted and manually copy and paste the new list. If this is something that will happen to frequently for that, you could also create a Dynamic SQL script to generate and execute your EXPDP command.

Hope this helps!

Documentation on Data Pump: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_export.htm#SUTIL200

Documentation on listagg function:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030