# Coversion of multiple rows into single row in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have one problem need to solve in oracle :

i/p :

```
O
R
A
C
L
E
```

O/P :

```
ORACLE
```

Comment: As you can see in hundreds of similiar questions on SO: use `listagg()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Query to concatenate column values from multiple rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686543/sql-query-to-concatenate-column-values-from-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: Here are [all the ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/468990/146325) to suit whichever version of Oracle you're using.

Comment: Are we to assume this is a column in a table with each value in it's own row, or a single column value containing a string with embedded carriage returns you need to remove?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a column in a table, here's an example using listagg() that may work for you

```
    select 
    listagg(your_column) within group (order by rn) new_column
    from (select rownum rn, your_column from your_table)
    ;
```

Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=87324175d17ef7806ccbedaefc05854e)