# How to convert a recordset to a delimited string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to convert a single column record set such as

```
1
2
3
```

into '1,2,3' string in SQL Server?

Comment: I know that I can use a cursor to do this but I want to know if there is a different way.

Comment: Does this have to be done at the sql level, or can you just take care of this on the consuming end programmatically?

Comment: Use `FOR XML PATH` or assign to a variable in a `SELECT`: possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180032/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Can I Comma Delimit Multiple Rows Into One Column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/sql-server-can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had success creating a function using Coalesce like below to do this.  You can then use the function in your select statement to get the delimited string.  (You can add parameters to your function and use them in the coalesce select statement as needed.)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MyFunction]
(
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR(2) 
    SET @Delimiter = ', '

    SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + @Delimiter,'') + AColumn
    FROM dbo.myTable

    RETURN RTRIM(LTRIM(@str))

END
```

Comment: Wait so what if I wanted to coalesce on a different table than myTable?  Are you going to create a function per table to save not having to remember coalesce or xml path?  (I prefer coalesce myself but that's because I just use it a lot, the xml path method is a perfectly reasonable way to do it.)  It's possible to create a SP do do this (multi table / multi column concatenation) but even then in my opinion it just seems like trying to hide what's actually happening)

Comment: (typo, had xmp on the brain today so everything was xmp_path this and xmp_path that, corrected)

Comment: Xml path works but automatically converts any special character to its entity reference (e.g. & becomes &amp;) which may not be desirable.  Plus you can have a fairly complicated select statement in your function if need be.  And yes, you would have to create a new function for other tables so this may not be the optimal solution in all cases either.

Comment: Also, the function solution works best if you want the delimited string to be one of multiple columns in your output.

Answer (score 6):

```
select stuff( (select ',' + YourColumn
               from YourTable
               for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Note: The stuff function just removes the first comma from the result string.

Answer (score 5):

COALESCE is decent way to do this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
DECLARE @Out VARCHAR(2048)
Select @Out = COALESCE(@Out + ', ', '') + [YourColumn] from YourTable

print @Out
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2017, you can use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(FirstName,'N/A')), ',') AS csv 
FROM Person.Person;
```