# Output a comma separated list in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with phone numbers in it. Instead of spitting out a single row for each number I want to return a comma separated list of phone numbers. What's the easiest way to do this in sql? A while loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-sub)

Comment: The basic idea of this question has been asked several times.  Take a look at the links provided in the answers below.

Comment: @TKTS - I wouldn't be surprised if this is the most rampant duplicate on SO. It seems to be asked at least once a day, sometimes more often.

Answer (score 9):

Some of those answers are overly complicated with coalesce and more complex XML queries. I use this all the time:

```
select @Phones=(
  Select PhoneColumn+','
  From TableName
  For XML Path(''))
-- Remove trailing comma if necessary
select @Phones=left(@Phones,len(@Phones)-1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a UDF that would do something like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetBirthdays(@UserId INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @combined VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @combined = COALESCE(@combined + ', ' + colName + ', colName)
FROM    YourTable
WHERE UserId = @UserId
ORDER BY ColName

END
```

Basically this just pulls all of the values into a simple list.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670920/how-to-convert-a-recordset-to-a-delimited-string-in-sql-server/4671068#4671068).  There are a couple of other ways to do it listed in that question also.  COALESCE or for xml path should do the trick though.

**Edit** (added my answer from the previous question):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_MyFunction]()RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
 AS 
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(MAX)    
    DECLARE @Delimiter CHAR(2)     
    SET @Delimiter = ', '    
    SELECT @str = COALESCE(@str + @Delimiter,'') + AColumn    
     FROM dbo.myTable    
    RETURN RTRIM(LTRIM(@str))
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I created a SQL CLR Aggregate function. Works like a champ!

> [Serializable]
>   [SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.UserDefined,
>   Name = "JoinStrings",
>   IsInvariantToNulls=true,
>   IsInvariantToDuplicates=false,
>   IsInvariantToOrder=false,
>   MaxByteSize=8000)] public struct
>   JoinStrings : IBinarySerialize {
>       public string Result;
>
> ```
> public void Init()
> {
>     Result = "";
> }
> public void Accumulate(SqlString value)
> {
>     if (value.IsNull)
>         return;
>
>     Result += value.Value + ",";
>
> }
> public void Merge(JoinStrings Group)
> {
>     Result += Group.Result;
> }
>
> public SqlString Terminate()
> {
>     return new SqlString(Result.ToString().Trim(new
> ```
>
> char[] { ',' }));
>       }
>
> ```
> public void Read(System.IO.BinaryReader r)
> {
>     Result = r.ReadString();
> }
>
> public void Write(System.IO.BinaryWriter w)
> {
>     w.Write(Result.ToString());
> } }
> ```

I can then use it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.JoinStrings(Phone) FROM Phones Where UserID = XXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Customers table which has a unique ID and another table named PhoneNumbers with multiple phone numbers for each customer sharing the Customer ID field as a Foreign Key this would work using a correlated sub-Query

```
Select C.ID, C.FirstName, C.LastName,
(select (STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + PhoneNumber from PhoneNumbers P where P.CID = C.ID
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''))) as PhoneNumbers
from Customers C
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Unique ID, Replace(Rtrim(Ltrim(Case when [Phone_Number1] is not null Then [Phone_Number1]+'  ' Else '' End +
                  Case when [Phone_Number2] is not null Then [Phone_Number2]+'  ' Else '' End +
                  Case when [Phone_Number3] is not null Then [Phone_Number3]+'  ' Else '' End)),'  ',', ') as Phone_numbers

From MYTable
```

Hope this is what you are looking for and I dont know if this will help you so far after the question.