# Select one field separated by comma

Tags: php, database, select

I want to select one column values separated by commas from the below table.

```
username
--------
   A
   B
   C
   D
```

I want the result like A,B,C,D.

Comment: See this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180032/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 5):

you can do it directly on your query. use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`username`)
FROM tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
$qry="select username from tableName ";
$exe=mysql_query($qry);
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($exe))
{
        $userName .=$r['username'].",";
}
$userName =substr($userName,0,-1);
echo $userName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT username FROM table_name';
$query = mysql_query($sql);

$csv = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $csv[] = $row['username'];
}

echo implode(',', $csv);
```