# Subquery to define Select list

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/84fff/10)

I would like to use a "subquery" to define the table columns I want to select.
The Fields table FieldName column contains the column names of the EDIFields Table along with others.

Something similar to the following:

```
SELECT ( SELECT FieldName 
         FROM FieldsTable ft 
         WHERE ft.FormatID = @FormatID 
           AND ft.Active != 0 ) 
From EDIFields
Where ...
```

Is it possible to do this in sql server 2008 r2 or can I get the results I want in another way?

example outputs:

```
@Active = 1
@FormatID = 1
PONUM  QTY
PO1    1
PO2    3
PO3    2

@Active = 1
@FormatID = 2
PONUM  TRANSID  MSG
PO1    T1       msg1
PO2    T1       msg2
PO3    T2       msg3

@Active = 1
@FormatID = 3    
TOTAL
56.65
67.43
100
```

With initial tables as follows:

EDIFields -

```
PONUM   TRANSID QTY MSG TOTAL
PO1     T1          1   msg1    56.65
PO2     T1          3   msg2    67.43
PO3     T2          2   msg3    100
```

Fields -

```
FIELDID FIELDNAME   FORMATID   ACTIVE
1           PONum           1      1
2           TransID         1      0
3           Qty             1      1
4           PONum           2      1
5           TransID         2      1
6           Msg             2      1
7           Total           3      1
```

Comment: hello, what is the output you expect ?

Comment: I have that in the sqlfiddle but I will copy and paste it to an edit.

Comment: Copy paste the output and not code.

Comment: so you need three queries for getting three outputs ?

Comment: I Dont need three, I just Need a query that takes the `@Active` and `@FormatID` and with the inputs as provided give the example outputs. The end goal is a SP with those as inputs and returns what ever columns match.

Comment: Okay, an SP which returns multiple, ie three resultsets.

Comment: NO, Sorry Im not being clear. An SP that takes `@Active` AND `@FormatID` and Returns a single result set. The `@Active` and `@FormatID` determine what columns are returned in that result set. The examples are as if you ran the SP three separate times each with the given inputs.

Comment: They determine the columns which are returned by the SP.

Comment: You need to use IF-THEN-ELSE to do this. But what you are attempting here doesn't seem right. Better have 3 different SPs and move the decision logic to the caller.

Comment: @Archangel33 - so, does my answer work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way would be to build a dynamic SQL statement

```
     DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @COLUMNLIST as nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @COLUMNLIST = coalesce(@COLUMNLIST +',', '') + '[' + FieldName + ']'  
         FROM FieldsTable ft 
         WHERE ft.FormatID = @FormatID 
           AND ft.Active != 0

set @SQL =  'select ' +  @COLUMNLIST + ' FROM EDIFields'
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Awesome I'm glad it was useful :-) It's always been a favorite query of mine... Originally I got the query from Pinal Dave. 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/   . Pinal is usually where I get 95 percent of my SQL questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Stored procedure -

```
Create  procedure getResults(
@Active int,
@FormatID int
)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @srcTable nvarchar(100)
Declare @ColumnList nvarchar(max)
Declare @sqlCmd nvarchar(max)
Set @srcTable = 'EDIFields'
Set @ColumnList = ''
Set @sqlCmd = 'SELECT '
-- Get the field list as a comma separated value
Select @ColumnList =  @ColumnList + fieldName + ','
from fields
where (formatId = @FormatID and active = @Active) 
-- Remove comma from last position of columnList
Set @ColumnList = LEFT(@ColumnList, LEN(@ColumnList) - 1)
-- Now add these columns to the sqlCmd
Set @sqlCmd = @sqlCmd + @ColumnList + ' FROM ' + @srcTable
-- Now your sql statement is ready to be executed
exec sp_executesql @sqlCmd
END
```

Comment: The critical post which helped me to convert a column into a CSV - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180032/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: Sample execution - `exec getResults 1,1`. I Hope you like ! It is nice. I like ! BTW, I don't use any functions like a `COALESCE`.

Comment: This works well too but I can only accept one answer.