# SQL query to get combine multiple id in single value with comma separators

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables `Employee and Skills` with following fields:

**Employee**:`Id,Name,Location`

**Skills**:`Id,Skills`

**Employee data**:

```
Id    Name   Location
7     Abc     London
8     Xyz     London
9     Xyz     USA
10    Abc     USA
```

**Skills**:

```
Id   skills     EmployeeId
12    AAA Xyz     7
13    BBB         7
14    CCC         7
15    AAA         8
16    BBB         8
17    CCC         8
18    AAA         9
19    BBB         9
20    CCC         9
21    AAA         10
22    BBB         10
20    CCC         10
```

Now I want to get **skills** of those employee whose `Name is Abc`,`Location is London and Skills is both AAA and BBB` **only** but I want single output like below:

```
Skills
10,11
```

This is my query:

```
select S.Id from Employee E inner join
Skills S on E.Id=s.EmployeeId
where (E.Name='Abc' and E.Location='London'
and s.skills='AAA') and (E.Name='Abc' and E.Location='London'
and s.skills='BBB')
```

But I am getting wrong output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I combine multiple rows into a comma-delimited list in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180032/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for this:

```
Select  Stuff
(
    (
        Select  ',' + Convert(Varchar, S.Id)
        From    Employee    E
        Join    Skills      S   On  S.EmployeeId = E.Id
        Where   E.Name = 'Abc'
        And     E.Location = 'London'
        And     S.Skills In ('AAA', 'BBB')
        For Xml Path ('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
) As Skills
```

**Edit**:  SQL Fiddle appears to not want to work with me at the moment, but using the following data (from OP), it does get the correct results:

```
Create Table Skills
(
  Id int,
  skills varchar (3),
  employeeid int
);

Create Table Employee
(
  Id int,
  Name varchar (10),
  location varchar (10)
  );

insert skills values 
(10    ,'AAA',      1),
(11    ,'BBB',      1),
(13    ,'CCC',      1),
(14    ,'DDD',      1);

insert employee values
(    1     ,'Abc' ,    'London'),
(    2     ,'Xyz',     'Uk');


Select  Stuff
(
    (
        Select  ',' + Convert(Varchar, S.Id)
        From    Employee    E
        Join    Skills      S   On  S.EmployeeId = E.Id
        Where   E.Name = 'Abc'
        And     E.Location = 'London'
        And     S.Skills In ('AAA', 'BBB')
        For Xml Path ('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
) As Skills
```

[image: Results]

**Edit #2** New data; same query:

```
Create Table Skills
(
  Id int,
  skills varchar (3),
  employeeid int
);

Create Table Employee
(
  Id int,
  Name varchar (10),
  location varchar (10)
  );

insert skills values
(12    ,'AAA',      7   ),
(13    ,'BBB',      7   ),
(14    ,'CCC',      7   ),
(15    ,'AAA',      8   ),
(16    ,'BBB',      8   ),
(17    ,'CCC',      8   ),
(18    ,'AAA',      9   ),
(19    ,'BBB',      9   ),
(20    ,'CCC',      9   ),
(21    ,'AAA',      10  ),
(22    ,'BBB',      10  ),
(20    ,'CCC',      10  );

insert employee values
(7     ,'Abc',     'London'  ),
(8     ,'Xyz',     'London'  ),
(9     ,'Xyz',     'USA'       ),
(10    ,'Abc',     'USA'       );


Select  Stuff
(
    (
        Select  ',' + Convert(Varchar, S.Id)
        From    Employee    E
        Join    Skills      S   On  S.EmployeeId = E.Id
        Where   E.Name = 'Abc'
        And     E.Location = 'London'
        And     S.Skills In ('AAA', 'BBB')
        For Xml Path ('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
) As Skills
```

[image: Results #2]

The results this time are `12,13` - which is correct based on your conditions:

Employee `7` is the only one with `Abc` from `London`, and `12` and `13` are the `AAA` and `BBB` skills.

Comment: How is it wrong?  What is it displaying?  I need a little more to go on...

Comment: I'd post a SQL Fiddle, but it doesn't want to work with me at the moment.  But using your sample data, I get the *exact* result you're asking for.

Comment: I did, and it's still the correct result.  See my edit.

Comment: I dont know  why this query is giving me unexpected output.You think if i have Location like this:New jersey and instead of london i am searching for this New jersey then this could be problem with space in my location field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115536/discussion-between-learning-and-siyual).

Comment: I'm not sure - please analyze the output you're getting.  What do those IDs map to?  Look at the data you have - does it make sense with those IDs?

Comment: Sorry i have not check properly with my records and so i was getting output like that.Your query is working perfect.Thank you so much