# remove duplicates from comma or pipeline operator string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have been looking into this for a while now and I cannot find a way to remove duplicate strings from a comma-separated as well as pipeline seperated string in SQL Server.

Given the string

```
test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4
```

does anyone know how would you return `test1,test2,test3,test4?`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

Comment: You convert `,` to rows, then `|` to rows, then select distinct between those rows. And then join back together.

Comment: The JOIN back part . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180032/how-can-i-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-comma-delimited-list-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: please explain with example code

Comment: If you are talking to me use `@username` . Just follow the link to see the solution.

Comment: please explain with example @Juan Carlos Oropeza

Comment: Again, on the link is all the info you need. I wont write the same answer again. Unless you dont understand the sql wrote there, and in that case you can ask for details.

Comment: i want it to be applied for both , and | , so i need to manipulate the answer

Comment: @NAVEENKUMARKR Apply the `REPLACE()` function on the column to replace commas with pipes, like this. `REPLACE(column, ',', '|')`. Now that you have a single delimiter, you can follow through with the links that Juan Carlos had provided to build your query. Those links contain code + explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach**

The following approach can be used to de-duplicate a delimited list of values.

1. Use the `REPLACE()` function to convert different delimiters into the same delimiter.
2. Use the `REPLACE()` function to inject XML closing and opening tags to create an XML fragment
3. Use the `CAST(expr AS XML)` function to convert the above fragment into the XML data type
4. Use `OUTER APPLY` to apply the table-valued function `nodes()` to split the XML fragment into its constituent XML tags. This returns each XML tag on a separate row.
5. Extract just the value from the XML tag using the `value()` function, and returns the value using the specified data type.
6. Append a comma after the above-mentioned value.
7. Note that these values are returned on separate rows. The usage of the `DISTINCT` keyword now removes duplicate rows (i.e. values).
8. Use the `FOR XML PATH('')` clause to concatenate the values across multiple rows into a single row.

**Query**

Putting the above approach in query form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PivotedTable.PivotedColumn.value('.','nvarchar(max)') + ',' 
FROM ( 
        -- This query returns the following in theDataXml column: 
        -- <tag>test1</tag><tag>test2</tag><tag>test1</tag><tag>test2</tag><tag>test3</tag><tag>test4</tag><tag>test4</tag><tag>test4</tag>
        -- i.e. it has turned the original delimited data into an XML fragment 
        SELECT 
          DataTable.DataColumn AS DataRaw 
        , CAST( 
            '<tag>' 
            -- First replace commas with pipes to have only a single delimiter 
            -- Then replace the pipe delimiters with a closing and opening tag 
            + replace(replace(DataTable.DataColumn, ',','|'), '|','</tag><tag>') 
            -- Add a final set of closing tags 
            + '</tag>' 
            AS XML) AS DataXml 
        FROM ( SELECT 'test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4' AS DataColumn) AS DataTable 
    ) AS x 
OUTER APPLY DataXml.nodes('tag') AS PivotedTable(PivotedColumn) 
-- Running the query without the following line will return the data in separate rows 
-- Running the query with the following line returns the rows concatenated, i.e. it returns: 
-- test1,test2,test3,test4, 
FOR XML PATH('')
```

**Input & Result**

Given the input:

> test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4

The above query will return the result:

> test1,test2,test3,test4,

Notice the trailing comma at the end. I'll leave it as an exercise to you to remove that.

---

**EDIT: Count of Duplicates**

OP requested in a comment "*how do i get t5he count of duplicates as well? in a seperate column*".

The simplest way would be to use the above query but remove the last line `FOR XML PATH('')`. Then, counting all values and distinct values returned by the `SELECT` expression in the above query (i.e. `PivotedTable.PivotedColumn.value('.','nvarchar(max)')`). The difference between the count of all values and the count of distinct values is the count of duplicate values.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(PivotedTable.PivotedColumn.value('.','nvarchar(max)'))            AS CountOfAllValues 
  , COUNT(DISTINCT PivotedTable.PivotedColumn.value('.','nvarchar(max)'))   AS CountOfUniqueValues 
    -- The difference of the previous two counts is the number of duplicate values 
  , COUNT(PivotedTable.PivotedColumn.value('.','nvarchar(max)')) 
    - COUNT(DISTINCT PivotedTable.PivotedColumn.value('.','nvarchar(max)')) AS CountOfDuplicateValues 
FROM ( 
        -- This query returns the following in theDataXml column: 
        -- <tag>test1</tag><tag>test2</tag><tag>test1</tag><tag>test2</tag><tag>test3</tag><tag>test4</tag><tag>test4</tag><tag>test4</tag>
        -- i.e. it has turned the original delimited data into an XML fragment 
        SELECT 
          DataTable.DataColumn AS DataRaw 
        , CAST( 
            '<tag>' 
            -- First replace commas with pipes to have only a single delimiter 
            -- Then replace the pipe delimiters with a closing and opening tag 
            + replace(replace(DataTable.DataColumn, ',','|'), '|','</tag><tag>') 
            -- Add a final set of closing tags 
            + '</tag>' 
            AS XML) AS DataXml 
        FROM ( SELECT 'test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4' AS DataColumn) AS DataTable 
    ) AS x 
OUTER APPLY DataXml.nodes('tag') AS PivotedTable(PivotedColumn)
```

For the same input shown above, the output of this query is:

```
CountOfAllValues CountOfUniqueValues CountOfDuplicateValues
---------------- ------------------- ----------------------
8                4                   4
```

Comment: how do i get t5he count of duplicates as well? in a seperate column

Comment: @NAVEENKUMARKR - I've revised the answer with a query for the same.

Comment: it became very helpfull

Answer (score 3):

Solution to your problem is as given below :

```
DECLARE @Data_String AS VARCHAR(1000), @Result as varchar(1000)=''
SET @Data_String = 'test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4'
SET @Data_String = REPLACE(@Data_String,'|',',')
SELECT @Result=@Result+col+',' from(
SELECT DISTINCT t.c.value('.','varchar(100)') col from(
SELECT cast('<A>'+replace(@Data_String,',','</A><A>')+'</A>' as     xml)col1)data cross apply col1.nodes('/A') as t(c))Data
SELECT LEFT(@Result,LEN(@Result)-1)
```

**Result**

```
test1,test2,test3,test4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(1000) 
    SET @string = 'test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4'
    SET @string = REPLACE(@string,'|',',')
    DECLARE @t TABLE (val VARCHAR(MAX)) 

    DECLARE @xml XML
    SET @xml = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(@string, ',', '</r><r>') +         '</r></root>'
    INSERT INTO @t(val) SELECT r.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as Item FROM         @xml.nodes('//root/r') AS RECORDS(r)
    ;WITH cte
    AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY val desc) RN
    FROM  @t)
    DELETE FROM cte
    WHERE  RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following SQL Script :

```
declare @List nvarchar(max)='test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4';
declare @Delimiter CHAR(1) =','
declare @XML AS XML
declare @result varchar(max)
set @List=Replace(@List,'|',',')
--Select @List

SET @XML = CAST(('<X>'+REPLACE(@List,@Delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML)
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Data nvarchar(100))
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') AS Data FROM @XML.nodes('X') AS T(N)
--SELECT distinct * FROM @temp

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp
Select distinct Data into #temp from @temp

SET @result = ''
select @result = @result + Data + ', ' from #temp
select SUBSTRING(@result, 0, LEN(@result))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried following script working perfectly :

```
declare @List VARCHAR(MAX)='test1,test2,test1|test2,test3|test4,test4|test4'
declare @Delim CHAR=','
DECLARE @ParsedList TABLE
(
Item VARCHAR(MAX)
)
DECLARE @list1 VARCHAR(MAX), @Pos INT, @rList VARCHAR(MAX)
set @List=Replace(@List,'|',',')
SET @list = LTRIM(RTRIM(@list)) + @Delim
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)
WHILE @pos > 0
BEGIN
SET @list1 = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @pos - 1)))
IF @list1 <> ''
INSERT INTO @ParsedList VALUES (CAST(@list1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)))
SET @list = SUBSTRING(@list, @pos+1, LEN(@list))
SET @pos = CHARINDEX(@delim, @list, 1)
END
SELECT @rlist = COALESCE(@rlist+',','') + item
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM @ParsedList) t
Select @rlist
```